# How can one change the timestamp of an old commit in Git?

Tags: git, timestamp, commit, git-rewrite-history

The answers to [How to modify existing, unpushed commits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179123/how-do-i-edit-an-incorrect-commit-message-in-git) describe a way to amend previous commit messages that haven't yet been pushed upstream.  The new messages inherit the timestamps of the original commits.  This seems logical, but is there a way to also re-set the times?

Comment: Related: [How to change git log date formats](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7853332/55075)

Comment: `git commit --amend --reset-author`

Comment: The comment above ^^ (@ErickM.Sprengel) should be the accepted answer. Easy to run, specially to the latest commit.

Comment: @WesleyGonçalves that is only a partial answer. What if you don’t want to set the commit time to right now? Your use case is not everyone’s use case.

Answer (score 665, accepted):

Use `git filter-branch` with an env filter that sets `GIT_AUTHOR_DATE` and `GIT_COMMITTER_DATE` for the specific hash of the commit you're looking to fix.

This will invalidate that and all future hashes.

**Example:**

If you wanted to change the [dates](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-commit.html#_date_formats) of commit `119f9ecf58069b265ab22f1f97d2b648faf932e0`, you could do so with something like this:

```
git filter-branch --env-filter \
    'if [ $GIT_COMMIT = 119f9ecf58069b265ab22f1f97d2b648faf932e0 ]
     then
         export GIT_AUTHOR_DATE="Fri Jan 2 21:38:53 2009 -0800"
         export GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="Sat May 19 01:01:01 2007 -0700"
     fi'
```

Comment: See "DATE FORMATS" https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-commit.html

Comment: That **found** the correct value, but just setting those variables didn't actually seem to affect the date of the old commit.

Comment: What do you mean by "This will invalidate that and all future hashes."?

Comment: if you get Namespace refs/original/ not empty error, you can run rm -  fr "$(git rev-parse --git-dir)/refs/original/"

Comment: EpicDavi: It means that you will have to force push to any remote repository, and anyone who has pulled the commit or any future commits will have to reset and pull, or delete and clone from scratch. As far as I know, there is no method that gets around this.

Comment: one question regarding the example values of AUTHOR/COMMITER date: What sense would it make for the author date to be after the commit date? When I look e.g. [here](http://alexpeattie.com/blog/working-with-dates-in-git/), the author date is explained as the date/time of the original "author's" commit, while commit date is the date this specific commit was applied - so under which circumstances would it make sense for the commit date to be before the author date?

Comment: @codeling I had this case lately. Consider rebasing an old branch (e.g. created a year ago) onto a recently created one. After the rebase the AUTHOR_DATE will have its original value from 2014, and the COMMITTER_DATE will reflect the date of rebase. Analogically if someone else was the author of the original commits, you'd have separate author (the original author) and commiter (the one who performed the rebase). This way you don't overwrite the original author and date with your data as the rebaser.

Comment: `GIT_AUTHOR_DATE` didn't work for me. had to use `--date="..."`.

Comment: A convenient implementation of @Dustin 's approach for bash:


```sh
function fix_commit_date {
  git filter-branch -f --env-filter "if [ \$GIT_COMMIT = $1 ]
                                     then
                                       export GIT_AUTHOR_DATE='$2'
                                       export GIT_COMMITTER_DATE='$2'
                                     fi"
}
```

Add to your `~/.bashrc` or ~/.bash_profile` at your own risk.

Then use:
```sh
$ fix_commit_date <COMMIT SHA> "<DATE>"
```

Comment: I don't want to wait for analyzing over 9000 commits!

Comment: Just as a note for beginners, the short hash does not work in the if statement, use the long SHA-1

Comment: It seems to be working. However I would like to patch multiple commits, but using this method, I can patch only one, then all subsequent patches on other commits seems to be ignored (the dates do not change despite of the executed command)

Comment: Great answer. Unforunately this doesn't work on MacOS: `Rewrite 5385b98dafc3007cf73a54116e962c54362e7bb0 (1/11) (0 seconds passed, remaining 0 predicted)    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/libexec/git-core/git-filter-branch: line 405: [: 5385b98dafc3007cf73a54116e962c54362e7bb0: unary operator expected`

Comment: I used this to un-restart commiter_date `git filter-branch --env-filter  'export GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="$GIT_AUTHOR_DATE"'`

Comment: Note: The Commit ID variable is the long hash version always. If you have only abbreviated commit IDs, [then expand them beforehand](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41717108/3894752), otherwise the check will fail.

Comment: So I ran this today (made a copy branch) but it ended up making me unable to merge to master since it rewrites the history with new commits.

Doing a git rebase solved it but then all my commits on that branch had the current date.

The way to fix It was to add the flag - `git rebase master --committer-date-is-author-date`

Comment: @codeling I think the answer to your (almost 8 year old question) is it doesn't make any sense to do that. I'm not sure if it was intentional but perhaps the example simply shows that you *can* do it if you wanted to.

Answer (score 1254):

You can do an interactive rebase and choose `edit` for the commit whose date you would like to alter. When the rebase process stops for amending the commit you type in for instance:

```sh
git commit --amend --date="Wed Feb 16 14:00 2011 +0100" --no-edit
```

P.S. `--date=now` will use the current time.

Afterward, you continue your interactive rebase.

To change the commit date instead of the author date:

```sh
GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="Wed Feb 16 14:00 2011 +0100" git commit --amend --no-edit
```

The lines above set an environment variable `GIT_COMMITTER_DATE` which is used in amending commit.

Everything is tested in Git Bash.

Comment: @nschum --date="" and --data"non-date-text" all yield the same, taking the date of now.

Comment: on git version 1.7.7.1 using --date="now" gives fatal: invalid date format: now

Comment: When the commit whose date you want to change is the most recent commit, you don't have to do the `rebase`, you can just do the `git commit --amend`

Comment: Instead of export GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="", try unset GIT_COMMITTER_DATE.

Comment: `export GIT_COMMITTER_DATE=""` doesn't delete the environment variable, it sets it to the empty string; I don't know how git will deal with that. As @mehaase say, `unset GIT_COMMITTER_DATE` is better -- but combining them into a single command, as in Luke Ehresman's answer, is even better; the environment variable setting applies only to that command.

Comment: @mehaase: or, simply  `GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="..." git commit --amend`

Comment: `GIT_AUTHOR_DATE` and `GIT_COMMITTER_DATE` are described at https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-commit.html in the 'date formats' section, fyi

Comment: I tried to do that, but the interactive rebase doesn't let me edit the commits even though I did replace "pick" with "edit". Anything I could be doing wrong?
I did `git rebase --interactive HEAD~7`, then edited the git-rebase-todo file (replace "pick" with "edit"), but every time I run `git rebase --continue` it just adds the next commit with no chance to modify it (kind of as if it was still a pick, but the console does read "edit").
When I try `git commit --amend --date="20160203T22:12:02"`, it tells me "fatal: You are in the middle of a cherry-pick -- cannot amend"

Comment: I'm using --no-edit so that you can use in automated scripts! `+    var fixedDate = strftime(new Date(), "%c");
+    var result = shelljs.exec("git commit --amend --date=\"" + fixedDate + "\" --no-edit");`

Comment: Just to let you guys know, I've created a NodeJS CLI to easily modify the previous git commit in your current directory. You can find it at https://github.com/samholmes1337/git-date or run `npm install -g git-date` to install and `git date <date string>` to run.

Comment: If you're an idiot like me, you missed the fact that the `--amend` commands *must be done inside a rebase*, not just willy-nilly from the command-line

Comment: Thanks! I just use `--date=now` and it worked. No need to bother with guessing formats when I want the current time

Comment: Won't this change the commit date of all the commits, except for the one being edited, to the current date-time? @PaulPladijs

Comment: To be self-contained, I'd recommend to explain how to do the "interactive rebase".

Comment: For anyone trying to execute this on Powershell, but failing, you need to do this in two separate commands, 1st set the env variable like `$env:GIT_COMMITTER_DATE` and do `git commit --amend --no-edit` after

Answer (score 457):

A better way to handle all of these suggestions in one command is

```
LC_ALL=C GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="$(date)" git commit --amend --no-edit --date "$(date)"
```

This will set the last commit's commit and author date to "right now."

Comment: This works great to edit specific commits during an interactive rebase.

Comment: You could add an alias to the shell for it too

Comment: It seems that Git isn't locale-aware of date format, so to be completely correct, you'll have to make it something like this: `LANG= GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="\`date\`" git commit --amend --date "\`date\`"`

Comment: I do that when I rebase and squash a branch, so it creates a single commit with an updated timestamp.

Comment: Another solution to locale problem is `GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="\`date -R\`" git commit --amend --date "\`date -R\`"`

Comment: Git isn't only used on systems with `bash`... This is useless in e.g. Powershell on Windows: `The term 'GIT_COMMITTER_DATE=date" git commit --amend --date date"' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.`

Comment: you can also just do `--date "now"`. Git >= 2 will interpret that.

Comment: You can also use `date --date="11 day ago"` to set a custom date

Comment: What does `LC_ALL=C` do?

Comment: @stwykd it ensures that `$(date)` uses a format that Git can understand, by temporarily overriding the system locale

Answer (score 357):

Just do `git commit --amend --reset-author --no-edit`. For older commits, you can do an interactive rebase and choose `edit` for the commit whose date you want to modify.

```
git rebase -i <ref>
```

Then amend the commit with `--reset-author` and `--no-edit` to change the author date to the current date:

```
git commit --amend --reset-author --no-edit
```

Finally continue with your interactive rebase:

```
git rebase --continue
```

Comment: good call on using `--reset-author`, it's new in git 1.6.6 (ref https://gitlog.wordpress.com/2010/01/13/git-1-6-6/ )

Comment: This works nicely to make Github show the commits of a rebased PR in the correct order, since [they order them by timestamp](https://help.github.com/articles/why-are-my-commits-in-the-wrong-order/) and without this trick, the timestamps may all be the same.

Comment: note `--reset-author` will reset both the Author and the Author Date to now.

Comment: will this change the "COMMITTER DATE" at the same time?

Comment: @luochen1990 no, this does not change the committer date, this only changes the author date

Comment: If the commit was recent, you can also do `git rebase -i HEAD~n` where `n` is the n-th commit.

Comment: For rebase, you can use `--ignore-date`

Comment: On git 2.39.0 at least, `--reset-author` also resets the `CommitDate`

Comment: Works great, I prefer using the reset author compared to the accepted answer.

Answer (score 225):

I wrote a script and Homebrew package for this. Super easy to install, you can find it on GitHub [`PotatoLabs/git-redate`](https://github.com/PotatoLabs/git-redate) page.

Syntax:

```
git redate -c 3
```

You just have to run `git redate` and you'll be able to edit all the dates in vim of the most recent 5 commits (there's also a `-c` option for how many commits you want to go back, it just defaults to 5). Let me know if you have any questions, comments, or suggestions!

[image]

Comment: Great stuff, even though I had to use vim rather than nano

Comment: Thanks @Edmund for a great script. I couldn't see the date to edit in vi after I ran git redate -c. All I see is %cI | XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX | Initial commit. Could you please help? Thanks

Comment: @KiemNguyen could you try just git redate (without the -c)?

Comment: Hi @Edmund I tried just git redate (without the -c) but it still doesn't show the date. It only show %cI as the date then my repo hash

Comment: @KiemNguyen Hm just pulled the file directly and ran it without being able to reproduce %cl issue. Did you perhaps install it through homebrew? I'll update the homebrew package to the latest version

Comment: @KiemNguyen update the homebrew package to v1.0.2, just tested and it still works

Comment: Awesome thanks @Edmund. I updated homebrew package then unlinked and reinstalled git-redate, now I can see the date now.

Comment: completely agree with Mina and @howdoyouturnthison here, why don't you make it editor agnostic via EDITOR environment variable? (also I'm on linux, not mac...)

Comment: Thanks @Edmund! Just in case, you script has a problem with handling default value for COMMITS. If it's not set, the following code applies filters just to (I guess/found) the last commit. "git filter-branch -f --env-filter "$ENVFILTER" HEAD~$COMMITS..HEAD >/dev/null"

Comment: Hello, I'm trying to edit simultaneous dates that occured 230 commits ago, after changing date, the scripts fails with `/mingw32/bin/git: Argument list too long` Is there any workaround? Thanks

Comment: useless, fails with error fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD~7..HEAD': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.

Comment: Works well, thanks for writing this.  Would be great to have a screenshot or more documentation of how it works - lets you edit the dates of each commit in a text editor (setting author and committer date).  However if you are in wrong directory or your working tree is unclean (uncommitted files), your edits are lost - so copy/paste them before exiting!

Comment: Works like a charm, even with those "strange" editors (I'm totally Windows user:)). I couldn't make it work with Notepad++ but the usage is so simple that even Nano was sufficient for this job. Thank you.

Comment: That's just wonderful! For some reason it didn't want to update the latest commit. When editing 3 commits, it didn't update the date for the oldest one, but I just used --commits 4, edited 3, and it worked. Thank you!

Comment: Nope. Not working.

Answer (score 189):

Each commit is associated with two dates, the *committer date* and the *author date*. You can view these dates with:

```
git log --format=fuller
```

If you want to change the author date and the committer date of the last 6 commits, you can simply use an interactive rebase :

```
git rebase -i HEAD~6
```

.

```
pick c95a4b7 Modification 1
pick 1bc0b44 Modification 2
pick de19ad3 Modification 3
pick c110e7e Modification 4
pick 342256c Modification 5
pick 5108205 Modification 6

# Rebase eadedca..5108205 onto eadedca (6 commands)
#
# Commands:
# p, pick = use commit
# r, reword = use commit, but edit the commit message
# e, edit = use commit, but stop for amending
# s, squash = use commit, but meld into previous commit
# f, fixup = like "squash", but discard this commit's log message
# x, exec = run command (the rest of the line) using shell
# d, drop = remove commit
```

For all commits where you want to change the date, replace `pick` by `edit` (or just `e`), then save and quit your editor.

You can now amend each commit by specifying the author date and the committer date in [ISO-8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format:

```
GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="2017-10-08T09:51:07" git commit --amend --date="2017-10-08T09:51:07"
```

The first date (`GIT_COMMITTER_DATE=`) is the *commit date*, the second one (`--date=`) is the *author date*.

Then go to the next commit with :

```
git rebase --continue
```

Repeat the process until you amend all your commits. Check your progression with `git status`.

Comment: I followed this and  ended up on a 'detatched head'!

Comment: @Simon H I've tested again my answer and it works well. You should have typed something different or you were already in a detached head. If you want to come back from a detached head do a `git checkout name-of-current-branch`.

Comment: This is the best and the easiest answer.

Small tip: use `--no-edit ` in `git commit --amend --no-edit --date=2017-10-08T09:51:07` to keep the old commit message.

Comment: You might also want to update `GIT_COMMITTER_DATE` 
 as described here http://eddmann.com/posts/changing-the-timestamp-of-a-previous-git-commit/

Comment: @smihael Thanks for the link. I've included your suggestion in my answer.

Comment: Great answer due to `git log --format=fuller` and the ability to change both dates in one command.

Comment: Thank you very much, it helped me to better understand how the "rebase" works

Comment: After I did this, `git status` reported that `Your branch and 'origin/main' have diverged` (I'm currently on the branch `main`). Using `git pull --ff-only` resulted in a fatal error: `Not possible to fast-forward, aborting`. What should I do to push the changes to commit times to GitHub?

Answer (score 136):

```
git commit --amend --date="now"
```

Comment: Thanks! Works great, although it works only for the most recent commit.

Comment: This is perfect for when squashing multiple commits into a single one, that always leaves the last commit's date, thanks!

Answer (score 126):

## How to Edit Multiple Commit Dates

Other answers aren't very convenient for editing several commit dates. I've come back to this question after a few years to share a technique.

To change the dates of the last 4 commits:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~4
```

Edit the rebase as follows, inserting `exec` lines to modify dates as needed:

```
pick 4ca564e Do something
exec git commit --amend --no-edit --date "1 Oct 2019 12:00:00 PDT"
pick 1670583 Add another thing
exec git commit --amend --no-edit --date "2 Oct 2019 12:00:00 PDT"
pick b54021c Add some tests
exec git commit --amend --no-edit --date "3 Oct 2019 12:00:00 PDT"
pick e8f6653 Fix the broken thing
exec git commit --amend --no-edit --date "4 Oct 2019 12:00:00 PDT"
```

#### Update (Sep. 2021):

If you want to see the original commit date in the rebase instruction list (Git 2.6+):

```
git config --add rebase.instructionFormat "[%ai] %s"
```

Then you'll see something like

```
pick 4f5a371f [2021-09-08 02:56:50 -0700] Add npm events
pick 67937227 [2021-09-09 03:05:42 -0700] Fixup
```

Comment: Is it possible to use current date/time as parameter?

Comment: Re. 'Is it possible to use current date/time as parameter?': "now" is understood as a valid date, so the exec lines above would become `exec git commit --amend --no-edit --date "now"`

Comment: As a addition I wrote a bash script which combines this answer (multiple commits) with the accepted answer (filter): https://gist.github.com/pixelbrackets/e2c2b451b77516e69377ecb4fd6f3a0d

Comment: for current date, you can do `exec git commit --amend --reset-author --no-edit`

Comment: To set the commit date and the author date together, you'll need to combine this with the [answer from Ortomala Lokni](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454734/how-can-one-change-the-timestamp-of-an-old-commit-in-git#41997774). So you will have to use commands like this: `exec GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="1 Oct 2019 12:00:00 PDT" git commit --amend --no-edit --date "1 Oct 2019 12:00:00 PDT"`

Answer (score 48):

After reading all the answers I came up with a more succinct and convenient way of editing the date of multiple commits at once without the need of rebasing interactively:

```
git rebase HEAD~4 --exec "git commit --amend --no-edit --date 'now'"
```

It changes both the committer and author dates.

Comment: I liked your answer, I needed all local commits so I did: `git rebase origin/main --exec "git commit --amend --reset-author --no-edit"`

Comment: Great solution. But I experience a strange issue. When I change all the dates and push it to a remote branch with `git push -f -u origin bugfix` and see it on Bitbucket page it still contains the previous commit dates. However it's reproducible not only with this solution but with others too. It looks like Git still holds the previous dates somewhere.

Comment: @ka3ak I see a commit has 2 dates/timestamps, `AuthorDate` and `CommitDate`, which can be shown using `git log --pretty=fuller` command, as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/git-dates?view=azure-devops). I guess Bitbucket shows the `CommitDate` instead of the `AuthorDate`. In this particular case I suggest using this command (where `t` is the date you want to set):`t='2017-09-01 12:34:56'; GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="$t" git commit --amend --no-edit --date="$t"`. This command will change both the `AuthorDate` and the `CommitDate`.

Comment: @PereJoanMartorell I'll try. But in the meantime I used the following approach:
While being on branch `bugfix` I executed `git checkout -b bugfix_copy; git reset bugfix; git rebase ...(change commit dates) ; git push origin +bugfix_copy:bugfix`. After the last command even Bitbucket showed current time for each commit on its page. I used this approach also because I wanted to keep the branch `bugfix` whose commit dates would be unchanged.

Comment: Contrary to what the answer claims, this does not change both committer and author dates. I wanted to edit in a change to make it so but "there are too many pending edits, please try again later." Here is an amended solution that follows the same approach: `t='2023-06-01T13:12:04'; git rebase HEAD~2 --exec "GIT_COMMITTER_DATE='$t' git commit --amend --no-edit --date '$t'"`. Replace date string with `now` or whatever date you want to use instead.

Answer (score 47):

Building on [theosp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/299920/theosp)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24105058/6309), I wrote a script called `git-cdc` (for change date commit) that I put in my `PATH`.

The name is important: `git-xxx` anywhere in your `PATH` allows you to type:

```
git xxx
# here
git cdc ...
```

That script is in bash, even on Windows (since Git will be calling it from its [msys environment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3144417/6309))

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# commit
# date YYYY-mm-dd HH:MM:SS

commit="$1" datecal="$2"
temp_branch="temp-rebasing-branch"
current_branch="$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)"

date_timestamp=$(date -d "$datecal" +%s)
date_r=$(date -R -d "$datecal")

if [[ -z "$commit" ]]; then
    exit 0
fi

git checkout -b "$temp_branch" "$commit"
GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="$date_timestamp" GIT_AUTHOR_DATE="$date_timestamp" git commit --amend --no-edit --date "$date_r"
git checkout "$current_branch"
git rebase  --autostash --committer-date-is-author-date "$commit" --onto "$temp_branch"
git branch -d "$temp_branch"
```

With that, you can type:

```
git cdc @~ "2014-07-04 20:32:45"
```

That would reset author/commit date of the commit before HEAD (`@~`) to the specified date.

```
git cdc @~ "2 days ago"
```

That would reset author/commit date of the commit before HEAD (`@~`) to the same hour, but 2 days ago.

---

[Ilya Semenov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/189806/ilya-semenov) mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454734/how-can-one-change-the-timestamp-of-an-old-commit-in-git/24584976#comment55924424_24584976):

> For OS X you may also install GNU `coreutils` (`brew install coreutils`), add it to `PATH` (`PATH="/usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin:$PATH"`) and then use "`2 days ago`" syntax.

Comment: For me this only worked with quoting the date and the time into one quote:  `git cdc @~ "2014-07-04 20:32:45` otherwise it would not recognize the time and hence obtain time 00:00:00 (it becomes the third argument).

Comment: For OS X you may also install GNU coreutils (`brew install coreutils`), add it to PATH (`PATH="/usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin:$PATH"`) and then use "2 days ago" syntax.

Comment: @IlyaSemenov Interesting. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: I am trying to use your first example but I keep getting "fatal: invalid date format:".  What date format is Mac OS X expecting?

Comment: @usbsnowcrash not sure on mac. Does the second example "`2 days ago`" work?

Comment: I installed coreutils and the second one worked for me

Answer (score 28):

Information from July 2022:

This one working amazing with current timestamp:

```
git commit --amend --date=now --no-edit
```

And this one - with any date format:

```
git commit --amend --date="Mon Jul 25 10:37:36 2022 +0300" --no-edit
```

Answer (score 27):

To change both the author date and the commit date:

```
GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="Wed Sep 23 9:40 2015 +0200" git commit --amend --date "Wed Sep 23 9:40 2015 +0200"
```

Comment: I’d just add `--no-edit` to this command, to avoid changing the commit message. Good job!

Answer (score 25):

I created this npm package to change date of old commits.

https://github.com/bitriddler/git-change-date

Sample Usage:

```
npm install -g git-change-date
cd [your-directory]
git-change-date
```

You will be prompted to choose the commit you want to modify then to enter the new date.

If you want to change a commit by specific hash run this `git-change-date --hash=[hash]`

Comment: I just wanted to say that this is great and worked beautifully. Thank you, you saved me a great deal of time!

Comment: @Kareem Elbahrawy
I am getting following error: Please help me (Git + Windows 10)

Command failed: cd C:\D\Projects\Git\xx-xx && git filter-branch -f --env-filter     'if [ $GIT_COMMIT = xxxxxx ]
     then
         export GIT_AUTHOR_DATE="Wed Jan 27 16:00:00 2021 +0530"
         export GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="Wed Jan 27 16:00:00 2021 +0530"
     fi'
fatal: $GIT_COMMIT: no such path in the working tree.
Use 'git <command> -- <path>...' to specify paths that do not exist locally.

Comment: I just wanted to say that it stuck on simple count = 3 and modifying second commit.  the error is stdout maxBuffer length exceeded. So I don't recommend this package. Just avoid it.

Answer (score 23):

if it is previous last commit.

```
git rebase  -i HEAD~2
git commit --amend --date=now
```

if you already push to orgin and can force use:

```
git push --force
```

if you can't force the push and if it is pushed, you can't change the commit! .

Answer (score 22):

The most simple way to modify the date and time of the last commit

```
git commit --amend --date="12/31/2021 @ 14:00"
```

Comment: This changes only the `AuthorDate`, not the `CommitDate`. You can see that it does not work by typing `git log --format=fuller`.

Comment: To also change the commit date after this: `git rebase --committer-date-is-author-date HEAD^`

Answer (score 20):

Here is a convenient alias that changes both commit and author times of the last commit to a time accepted by `date --date`:

```
[alias]
    cd = "!d=\"$(date -d \"$1\")\" && shift && GIT_COMMITTER_DATE=\"$d\" \
            git commit --amend --date \"$d\""
```

Usage: `git cd <date_arg>`

Examples:

```
git cd now  # update the last commit time to current time
git cd '1 hour ago'  # set time to 1 hour ago
```

**Edit:**
Here is a more-automated version which checks that the index is clean (no uncommitted changes) and reuses the last commit message, or fails otherwise (fool-proof):

```
[alias]
    cd = "!d=\"$(date -d \"$1\")\" && shift && \
        git diff-index --cached --quiet HEAD --ignore-submodules -- && \
        GIT_COMMITTER_DATE=\"$d\" git commit --amend -C HEAD --date \"$d\"" \
        || echo >&2 "error: date change failed: index not clean!"
```

Comment: And the author change, @eold?

Answer (score 19):

The following bash function will change the time of any commit on the current branch.

Be careful not to use if you already pushed the commit or if you use the commit in another branch.

```
# rewrite_commit_date(commit, date_timestamp)
#
# !! Commit has to be on the current branch, and only on the current branch !!
# 
# Usage example:
#
# 1. Set commit 0c935403 date to now:
#
#   rewrite_commit_date 0c935403
#
# 2. Set commit 0c935403 date to 1402221655:
#
#   rewrite_commit_date 0c935403 1402221655
#
rewrite_commit_date () {
    local commit="$1" date_timestamp="$2"
    local date temp_branch="temp-rebasing-branch"
    local current_branch="$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)"

    if [[ -z "$date_timestamp" ]]; then
        date="$(date -R)"
    else
        date="$(date -R --date "@$date_timestamp")"
    fi

    git checkout -b "$temp_branch" "$commit"
    GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="$date" git commit --amend --date "$date"
    git checkout "$current_branch"
    git rebase "$commit" --onto "$temp_branch"
    git branch -d "$temp_branch"
}
```

Comment: You have a bug in there:  `if [[ -z "$commit" ]]` -> `if [[ -z "$date_timestamp" ]]`

Comment: Nice! I would recommend setting `GIT_COMMITTER_DATE=` at the end of the method to prevent any further manual commits to keep the date specified.

Comment: @loopkin, GIT_COMMITTER_DATE is set just for the "git commit" command so no need to clear it afterwards

Comment: @nimrodm, I just tested again and you are correct. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 11):

If you want to get the exact date of another commit (say you rebase edited a commit and want it to have the date of the original pre-rebase version):

```
git commit --amend --date="$(git show -s --format=%ai a383243)"
```

This corrects the date of the HEAD commit to be *exactly* the date of commit a383243 (include more digits if there are ambiguities). It will also pop up an editor window so you can edit the commit message.

That's for the author date which is what you care for usually - see other answers for the committer date.

Answer (score 11):

If commit not yet pushed then I can use something like that:

```
git commit --amend --date=" Wed Mar 25 10:05:44 2020 +0300"
```

after that git bash opens editor with the already applied date so you need just to save it by typing in the VI editor command mode ":wq" and you can push it

Comment: Just adding to the nice answer: if you don't want to edit the commit message (if you just want to change the commit date), use the `--no-edit` option.

Comment: Also, if the commit has already been pushed, you can still push the changed commit using `git push -f` (forced update). That may have side effects, though. (especially if many people have local clones of the repository)

Answer (score 10):

```
GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="Sun Nov 20 21:02 2022 +0530" git commit --amend --no-edit --date="Sun Nov 20 21:02 2022 +0530"
git push -f
```

Works everytime.

Comment: why do we need to specify the time twice?

Comment: This is my guess: there are two timestamps in git: committer date and authoring date. GIT_COMMITTER_DATE takes care of the former and --date takes care of the latter.

Answer (score 9):

### Set the date of the last commit to the current date

```
GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="$(date)" git commit --amend --no-edit --date "$(date)"
```

### Set the date of the last commit to an arbitrary date

```
GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="Mon 20 Aug 2018 20:19:19 BST" git commit --amend --no-edit --date "Mon 20 Aug 2018 20:19:19 BST"
```

### Set the date of an arbitrary commit to an arbitrary or current date

Rebase to before said commit and stop for amendment:

1. `git rebase <commit-hash>^ -i`
2. Replace `pick` with `e` (edit) on the line with that commit (the first one)
3. quit the editor (ESC followed by `:wq` in VIM)
4. Either:

- `GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="$(date)" git commit --amend --no-edit --date "$(date)"`
- `GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="Mon 20 Aug 2018 20:19:19 BST" git commit --amend --no-edit --date "Mon 20 Aug 2018 20:19:19 BST"`

Source:
https://codewithhugo.com/change-the-date-of-a-git-commit/

Answer (score 9):

For updating the date of the 5 last commits to the current date (this method doesn't allow to update the initial commit):

```
git rebase HEAD~5 --exec "git commit --amend --no-edit --date 'now'"
```

For all commits *after* commit 95f5074…15074db2:

```
git rebase 95f5074…15074db2 --exec "git commit --amend --no-edit --date 'now'"
```

For all commits (including the initial commit):

```
git rebase --root --exec "git commit --amend --no-edit --date 'now'"
```

Add `-i` for the interactive mode.

Run `git log --format=fuller --show-signature` to validate the changes.

Run `git push -f` to update the remote repository (⚠️Danger zone)

There are implications. For instance:

- Commit IDs will change, so you will have to recreate tags
- You will lose original signatures
- This will use your `.gitconfig`, this means your key will be used for signing commits (if Git is configured to sign commits)

Comment: Instead of changing the date of the last 3 commits, is it possible to change the --date and env variable GIT_COMMITTER_DATE of only the THIRD commit with a single command?

Answer (score 8):

If you want to perform the accepted answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/454750/72809) in standard Windows command line, you need the following command:

```
git filter-branch -f --env-filter "if [ $GIT_COMMIT = 578e6a450ff5318981367fe1f6f2390ce60ee045 ]; then export GIT_AUTHOR_DATE='2009-10-16T16:00+03:00'; export GIT_COMMITTER_DATE=$GIT_AUTHOR_DATE; fi"
```

Notes:

- It may be possible to split the command over multiple lines (Windows supports line splitting with the carret symbol `^`), but I didn't succeed.
- You can write ISO dates, saving a lot of time finding the right day-of-week and general frustration over the order of elements.
- If you want the Author and Committer date to be the same, you can just reference the previously set variable.

Many thanks go to a [blog post by Colin Svingen](http://swoogan.blogspot.com/2015/06/changing-date-on-series-of-git-commits.html). Even though his code didn't work for me, it helped me find the correct solution.

Answer (score 7):

For those using Powershell

```
git rebase DESIRED_REF^ -i

$commitDateString = "2020-01-22T22:22:22"
$env:GIT_COMMITTER_DATE = $commitDateString
git commit --amend --date $commitDateString
$env:GIT_COMMITTER_DATE = ""

git rebase --continue
```

Credit to https://mnaoumov.wordpress.com/2012/09/23/git-change-date-of-commit/

Answer (score 7):

Edit the author date and the commit date of the last 3 commits:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~3 --committer-date-is-author-date --exec "git commit --amend --no-edit --date=now"
```

The `--exec` command is appended after each line in the rebase and you can choose the author date with the `--date=...`, the committer date will be the same of author date.

Comment: I get "fatal: cannot combine apply options with merge options"

Comment: Git status is clean? The command is exactly that above?

Answer (score 5):

In addition to [Matt Montag's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58622282/10608621):

If you need to reset timestamp to ***current time*** after rebase command

```
git rebase -i HEAD~2
```

you can use one of these options

```
pick 4ca564e Do something
exec git commit --amend --no-edit --date=now
pick 1670583 Add another thing
exec git commit --amend --no-edit --reset-author
```

Both will work

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to make sure that I update my code’s copyright comments at precisely midnight, and I didn’t want to risk a tiny delay with [at](https://linux.die.net/man/1/at) or [cron](https://linux.die.net/man/8/cron). So, I commited the code and then:

```
GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="Fri Jan 1 00:00:00 2021 +1000" git commit --amend --no-edit --date="Fri Jan 1 00:00:00 2021 +1000"
```

(Or perhaps even set the UTC offset to 0? Decisions… ) Now I can push!

Happy new year, everybody

Answer (score 1):

There are already many great answers, but when I want to change date for multiple commits in one day or in one month, I don't find a proper answer. So I create a new script for this with explaintion, hope it will help someone:

```
#!/bin/bash

# change GIT_AUTHOR_DATE for commit at Thu Sep 14 13:39:41 2017 +0800
# you can change the data_match to change all commits at any date, one day or one month
# you can also do the same for GIT_COMMITTER_DATE

git filter-branch --force --env-filter '

date_match="^Thu, 14 Sep 2017 13+"              

# GIT_AUTHOR_DATE will be @1505367581 +0800, Git internal format 
author_data=$GIT_AUTHOR_DATE;                   
author_data=${author_data#@}                  
author_data=${author_data% +0800}                # author_data is 1505367581     

oneday=$((24*60*60))

# author_data_str will be "Thu, 14 Sep 2017 13:39:41 +0800", RFC2822 format
author_data_str=`date -R -d @$author_data`      

if [[ $author_data_str =~ $date_match ]];
then
    # remove one day from author_data
    new_data_sec=$(($author_data-$oneday))
    # change to git internal format based on new_data_sec
    new_data="@$new_data_sec +0800"             
    export GIT_AUTHOR_DATE="$new_data"
fi
' --tag-name-filter cat -- --branches --tags
```

The date will be changed:

```
AuthorDate: Wed Sep 13 13:39:41 2017 +0800
```

Answer (score 1):

I have recently needed this and made my own script looking a lot like git-redate

However my scripts does the minimal modifications and takes a lot less time to rewrite (if you need to update) many commits as it does them all at once

[change_git_history](https://github.com/erwanvivien/change_git_history)

Actually this allows to change commit messages too

## Explaination:

The scripts concatenates a bunch of bash if-expression looking like so

Here are the ones modifiying the commit date

```bash
if [ "$GIT_COMMIT" = "$com_hash" ]; # com is commit
then
    export GIT_AUTHOR_DATE="$com_date";
    export GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="$com_date";
fi;
```

Here are the ones modifiying the commit message:

```bash
if [ true = false ]; # impossible
then
    : # pass
elif [ "$GIT_COMMIT" = "$com_hash" ];
then
    sed 's/.*/$com_msg_esc/g' # replace content with new content
else
    cat - # returns previous content
fi;
```

And we push all the update using

```bash
git filter-branch -f \
    --env-filter "$UPDATES" \
    --msg-filter "$MESSAGES" \
    -- "$REV"
```

(doc is here [filter-branch man](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/git-filter-branch.1.html))

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30802372)

Comment: Thanks @SimasJoneliunas I've update the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR:** Matching dates + re-creating GPG signatures

<sup><sup>(Comment/edit if you know a workaround for the stripping to preserve the **original** signature.)</sup></sup>

---

I'll bump this old thread because a feature of signing commits has been introduced and all of these `git filter-branch` and likes basically strip the signatures as specified in the docs:

> ... If the tag has a signature attached, the signature will be stripped. It is by definition impossible to preserve signatures. ... (source: [--tag-name-filter](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch) )

But it'll also break the pretty [`Verified`](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/managing-commit-signature-verification/about-commit-signature-verification) badge on a GitHub commit (and in other Git hosting places if implemented in the same way), so this will fix that as well. **Partially.**

Afaik it's not possible to mangle a (GPG) signature through `git` command in a way that it **also** contains the date  of a commit instead of the date of signing [in a simple way](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/153402/106776) and therefore even if the dates for authoring and commit are moved, it'll still be the present date, example:

```
commit <hash>
gpg: Signature made Sun 25 Jul 2021 00:00:00 PM TZ
gpg:                using TYPE key KEY
gpg: Good signature from "Signer <email@domain.tld>"
Author:     Author <email@domain.tld>
AuthorDate: Sat Jan 1 00:00:00 2000 +0000
Commit:     Author <email@domain.tld>
CommitDate: Sat Jan 1 00:00:00 2000 +0000
```

So imagine you have a repo you want to sign from a certain commit (I'll go for the root commit; not recommended if somebody else works on the repo). The documentation for `git commit` [says](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#_commit_information) it pulls data from env vars too, if present, thus we have a place to put the input to.

To retrieve the data (can be set with `git commit --date=...`) we can take a look at [`git show --format=%ad`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show#Documentation/git-show.txt-emadem), so for a raw date string that would be:

```
git show --format=%ad --no-patch
# Sat Jan 1 00:00:00 2000 +0000
```

So we have:

- point of start
- raw date string for each commit
- `GIT_COMMITTER_DATE` to match the dates (author -> committer)

For rebasing let's do this:

```
git rebase --root <branch-name> --keep-empty --interactive
```

which will go for the root commit of a branch `<branch-name>`, preserve any empty commits created with `git commit -m "empty" --allow-empty` and ask you which commits to modify. There you change the desired commits from `pick` to `edit` (for my case that'd be marking all of them as `edit`), then you'll be dropped into a detached `HEAD` commit and from here the fun begins.

```sh
# or "while :"
while true
do
    GIT_COMMITTER_DATE=$(git show --format=%ad --no-patch) \
        git commit --amend --gpg-sign --no-edit --allow-empty
    git rebase --continue
done
```

<sup>(if you do not have `user.signingkey` specified, use `--gpg-sign=<fingerprint>`)</sup>

This will go through each of the `edit`-marked commit, set the committer's date to match the author's date, keep any empty commit, won't touch the overall patch body and will add a signature with a date of when the command was executed.

Once you see `fatal: No rebase in progress?` press `Ctrl-C` to stop the loop and check the logs to confirm that the dates match and the signatures are present everywhere with:

```
git log --pretty=fuller --show-signature
```

If everything is okay in the logs, simply issue `git push --force` and you're done. Now you should see that `Verified` badge for each commit.

[Example with a real history tree](https://github.com/KeyWeeUsr/Butch/commits/300a2eeb71480682851e8f8ba6b4f13e0665542b). GitHub doesn't seem to care about the signature's date (no reference anywhere), but it'll still be present in the `git log`.