# Windows 7 and git: how to invoke git from a system() call in a script

Tags: python, ruby, git, windows-7

I am on a windows 7 box that has msysgit installed. I also have a ruby script where I am trying to invoke git using a system() call.

```
system("C:/Programs/msysgit/bin/git.exe")
```

This does not work. Does anyone know how to get this running? I've done it on Win XP before, but cannot seem to get it working. Any example with ruby/perl/python or similar on windows will help.

Comment: Are you sure it's `C:/Programs/` and not `C:/Program Files/`?

Comment: What do you mean it "does not work"? What happened, and what did you expect to happen instead? Error messages? Return values?

Comment: Expected to see the output of the git commands in the console, instead saw no output. I know ruby is working because the output of my testing "puts(1212)" does show up. I guess I need to look on the windows XP box where the command does work, and see what they PATH= environment variable points to, then make Windows7 do the same

Comment: This turned out to be the issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3431361/git-for-windows-the-program-cant-start-because-libiconv2-dll-is-missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a missing file, see this post for the issue:

[Git for Windows - The Program can't start because libiconv2.dll is missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3431361/git-for-windows-the-program-cant-start-because-libiconv2-dll-is-missing)

Answer (score 1):

you need to be in a working tree of a repository. Or, some git commands allow `--git-dir` parameter to indicate where the repository is. The current directory that git.exe is running in is probably not a repository.

Comment: Doesn't matter if you are just calling git.exe

Answer (score 1):

If it is in PATH:

```
`git subcommand`
```

should work in ruby