# Problem installing MSysGit (libiconv-2.dll is missing...)

Tags: git, windows-7, msysgit

I'm trying to install [MSysGit using the netinstaller](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/MSysGit:InstallMSysGit) and when I run the netinstaller an error pops up:

The program can't start because libiconv-2.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.

After searching a bit, it doesn't seem like many people are having this issue during installation; only later on.

This is a fresh Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit install so if the installer is working, it should've worked here. Anyone had a similar issue or know what I might be able to do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was also asked on the msysGit mailing list, where the msysGit developers (including yours truly) hang out. As a consequence of that mail, I fixed it.

Comment: Heads up - so far as I know (and not to repost to that thread on the mailing list) the issue Drew mentioned still happens with sub module updates: http://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/msysgit/twrVn_EbNI4

Comment: fyi better option would be a soft link like so: cmd /c mklink \path\to\git\libexec\git-core\libiconv-2.dll \most\likely\mingw\libiconv-2.dll

Answer (score 1):

I've never user the netinstaller, but http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/detail?name=Git-1.7.4-preview20110204.exe&can=2&q is absolutely working fine on my Windows 7 Pro - 64 bit -system.

Edit:
maybe that [Git for Windows - The Program can't start because libiconv2.dll is missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3431361/git-for-windows-the-program-cant-start-because-libiconv2-dll-is-missing) can be the solution

Comment: It says in the documentation that the `Git-` is the installer for git, and the `msysgit-` is the installer for msysgit.

Comment: Sorry, trying to give a fast answer without exact reading the question is definitely not the best way. But I tried it out now and got the same error.

Comment: The full installer works just fine and is no different than the netinstaller if you follow the steps and execute `initialize.sh`