# git-credential-winstore prompt does not work with self hosted repositories

Tags: git, windows-7, credentials

git-credential-winstore works perfect with github and bitbucket repositories, but the prompt does not pop up while working with self hosted repositories. I can' t see what the problem is.

I' ve tried :

```
git config --global credential.helper winstore
```

via console

```
[credential]
    helper = winstore
```

in gitconfig and created and stored the credentials manualy. Without success.
Can anyone point me to te right direction please? Im using Win7.

Best regards.

Answer (score 21):

Copy `git-credential-winstore.exe` into `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\libexec\git-core`

Comment: I had to copy it to `C:\Program Files\GitExtensions\GitCredentialWinStore\` on a Windows 8 machine. Thanks for the link @kio21

Comment: Windows 7, libiconv-2.dll was missing => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3431361/git-for-windows-the-program-cant-start-because-libiconv2-dll-is-missing

Answer (score 4):

Use "wincred" in place of "winstore". It will work. It solved same problem for me.

Answer (score 2):

Execute 'git-credential-winstore.exe' and say 'yes'.

Answer (score 1):

Update 2016:

Use the Git Credential for Windows:
[available here on Microsoft's GitHub organisation account](https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows)

Install it and it just works, nothing to configure.