# libiconv-2_.dll is missing

Tags: qt, dll, cmd, qt-creator

I am working with a Qt project that can run from cmd line or from inside Qt creator.

When i run the project from the cmd line i get the message:
**The program can't start because libiconv-2_.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem**

When ran from Qt it just crashes and says the program terminated with exit code 1.

However, when i search my computer i find libiconv-2.dll inside Program Files (x86)\Git\bin.

I copy that dll into my working directory and change the name to include the "_" at the end (yes i know this is a terrible idea) and that makes the issue go away. But i know that is definitely not the proper solution to this.

I have searched all over the internet for any hits or tips on what the underscore means, but the only thing i found is someone with the same exact issue as me on here and the only answer given was to just include the _ in the name...

Does anyone else have any idea what the issue is?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git for Windows - The Program can't start because libiconv2.dll is missing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3431361/git-for-windows-the-program-cant-start-because-libiconv2-dll-is-missing)

Comment: @DavidPostill I dont believe its the same issue. His says "libiconv-2.dll is missing", notice how the one there does not have the underscore in the name. 

I have been trying to find anyone who has an idea of what the underscore means. But i have had no luck.

Comment: Part of the dupe answer correctly points out that the `.dll` files belong in `Git\lib` not `Git\\bin` so that is where you should place your renamed `.dll` file. I don't know about the `_` bit. Did you try reinstallling Git?