# Continously getting error while trying to install learnyounode and git-it on npm

Tags: node.js, git, npm

I am learning node.js with learnyounode from nodeschool.io, every time i try to install the module with the command `npm install -g learnyounode`, i am getting the error:

```
> npm ERR! exited with error code: 3221225781
```

It throws the same error while installing git-it module too.
Here is the snippet from my command prompt while trying to install the module.

```
> C:\Users\Abhinav>npm install -g learnyounode
npm ERR! Error while executing:
npm ERR! C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.EXE ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/c
odeclimate/javascript-test-reporter.git
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! exited with error code: 3221225781

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Abhinav\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-07-26T08_28_3
3_282Z-debug.log
```

Can anyone please help me out.

Snippet from `C:\Users\Abhinav\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-07-26T08_28_3`

```
    0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Users\\Abhinav\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\node\\bin\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\Abhinav\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   '-g',
1 verbose cli   'learnyounode' ]
2 info using npm@5.3.0
3 info using node@v6.11.1
4 verbose npm-session b36eabc72004180e
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readGlobalPackageData
7 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/learnyounode 1254ms (from cache)
8 silly pacote tag manifest for learnyounode@latest fetched in 1303ms
9 silly install loadIdealTree
10 silly install cloneCurrentTreeToIdealTree
11 silly install loadShrinkwrap
12 silly install loadAllDepsIntoIdealTree
13 silly resolveWithNewModule learnyounode@3.5.10 checking installable status
14 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/boganipsum 429ms (from cache)
15 silly pacote range manifest for boganipsum@~0.1.0 fetched in 434ms
16 silly resolveWithNewModule boganipsum@0.1.0 checking installable status
17 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/duplexer 593ms (from cache)
18 silly pacote range manifest for duplexer@^0.1.1 fetched in 618ms
19 silly resolveWithNewModule duplexer@0.1.1 checking installable status
20 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/hyperquest 683ms (from cache)
21 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/rimraf 694ms (from cache)
22 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/through 690ms (from cache)
23 silly pacote range manifest for hyperquest@^2.0.0 fetched in 698ms
24 silly resolveWithNewModule hyperquest@2.1.2 checking installable status
25 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/bl 704ms (from cache)
26 silly pacote range manifest for rimraf@^2.5.4 fetched in 706ms
27 silly resolveWithNewModule rimraf@2.6.1 checking installable status
28 silly pacote range manifest for through@^2.3.8 fetched in 702ms
29 silly resolveWithNewModule through@2.3.8 checking installable status
30 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/combined-stream 716ms (from cache)
31 silly pacote range manifest for bl@^1.1.2 fetched in 720ms
32 silly resolveWithNewModule bl@1.2.1 checking installable status
33 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/after 736ms (from cache)
34 silly pacote range manifest for combined-stream@^1.0.5 fetched in 740ms
35 silly resolveWithNewModule combined-stream@1.0.5 checking installable status
36 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/concat-stream 742ms (from cache)
37 silly pacote range manifest for after@~0.8.1 fetched in 748ms
38 silly resolveWithNewModule after@0.8.2 checking installable status
39 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/through2 314ms (from cache)
40 silly pacote range manifest for concat-stream@^1.5.1 fetched in 747ms
41 silly resolveWithNewModule concat-stream@1.6.0 checking installable status
42 silly pacote range manifest for through2@^2.0.1 fetched in 319ms
43 silly resolveWithNewModule through2@2.0.3 checking installable status
44 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/colors-tmpl 758ms (from cache)
45 silly pacote range manifest for colors-tmpl@^1.0.0 fetched in 763ms
46 silly resolveWithNewModule colors-tmpl@1.0.0 checking installable status
47 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/through2-map 348ms (from cache)
48 silly pacote range manifest for through2-map@^3.0.0 fetched in 353ms
49 silly resolveWithNewModule through2-map@3.0.0 checking installable status
50 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/workshopper-adventure 373ms (from cache)
51 silly pacote range manifest for workshopper-adventure@^6.0.0 fetched in 383ms
52 silly resolveWithNewModule workshopper-adventure@6.0.2 checking installable status
53 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/workshopper-wrappedexec 371ms (from cache)
54 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/workshopper-exercise 380ms (from cache)
55 silly pacote range manifest for workshopper-wrappedexec@~0.1.1 fetched in 376ms
56 silly resolveWithNewModule workshopper-wrappedexec@0.1.3 checking installable status
57 silly pacote range manifest for workshopper-exercise@^3.0.1 fetched in 385ms
58 silly resolveWithNewModule workshopper-exercise@3.0.1 checking installable status
59 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/readable-stream 178ms (from cache)
60 silly pacote range manifest for readable-stream@^2.0.5 fetched in 178ms
61 silly resolveWithNewModule readable-stream@2.3.3 checking installable status
62 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/core-util-is 249ms (from cache)
63 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/string_decoder 249ms (from cache)
64 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/inherits 254ms (from cache)
65 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/util-deprecate 254ms (from cache)
66 silly pacote range manifest for core-util-is@~1.0.0 fetched in 259ms
67 silly resolveWithNewModule core-util-is@1.0.2 checking installable status
68 silly pacote range manifest for string_decoder@~1.0.3 fetched in 264ms
69 silly resolveWithNewModule string_decoder@1.0.3 checking installable status
70 silly pacote range manifest for inherits@~2.0.3 fetched in 264ms
71 silly resolveWithNewModule inherits@2.0.3 checking installable status
72 silly pacote range manifest for util-deprecate@~1.0.1 fetched in 264ms
73 silly resolveWithNewModule util-deprecate@1.0.2 checking installable status
74 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/safe-buffer 269ms (from cache)
75 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/isarray 269ms (from cache)
76 silly pacote range manifest for safe-buffer@~5.1.1 fetched in 274ms
77 silly resolveWithNewModule safe-buffer@5.1.1 checking installable status
78 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/process-nextick-args 274ms (from cache)
79 silly pacote range manifest for isarray@~1.0.0 fetched in 284ms
80 silly resolveWithNewModule isarray@1.0.0 checking installable status
81 silly pacote range manifest for process-nextick-args@~1.0.6 fetched in 284ms
82 silly resolveWithNewModule process-nextick-args@1.0.7 checking installable status
83 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/colors 177ms (from cache)
84 silly pacote range manifest for colors@~1.0.2 fetched in 206ms
85 silly resolveWithNewModule colors@1.0.3 checking installable status
86 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/delayed-stream 188ms (from cache)
87 silly pacote range manifest for delayed-stream@~1.0.0 fetched in 193ms
88 silly resolveWithNewModule delayed-stream@1.0.0 checking installable status
89 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/typedarray 193ms (from cache)
90 silly pacote range manifest for typedarray@^0.0.6 fetched in 218ms
91 silly resolveWithNewModule typedarray@0.0.6 checking installable status
92 silly pacote range manifest for through2@~0.6.3 fetched in 12ms
93 silly resolveWithNewModule through2@0.6.5 checking installable status
94 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/duplexer2 233ms (from cache)
95 silly pacote range manifest for duplexer2@~0.0.2 fetched in 245ms
96 silly resolveWithNewModule duplexer2@0.0.2 checking installable status
97 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/buffer-from 245ms (from cache)
98 silly pacote range manifest for buffer-from@^0.1.1 fetched in 250ms
99 silly resolveWithNewModule buffer-from@0.1.1 checking installable status
100 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/is-array-buffer-x 191ms (from cache)
101 silly pacote range manifest for is-array-buffer-x@^1.0.13 fetched in 196ms
102 silly resolveWithNewModule is-array-buffer-x@1.3.0 checking installable status
103 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/is-object-like-x 228ms (from cache)
104 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/to-string-tag-x 238ms (from cache)
105 silly pacote range manifest for is-object-like-x@^1.3.0 fetched in 248ms
106 silly resolveWithNewModule is-object-like-x@1.3.0 checking installable status
107 silly pacote range manifest for to-string-tag-x@^1.4.0 fetched in 253ms
108 silly resolveWithNewModule to-string-tag-x@1.4.0 checking installable status
109 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/has-to-string-tag-x 253ms (from cache)
110 silly pacote range manifest for has-to-string-tag-x@^1.4.0 fetched in 253ms
111 silly resolveWithNewModule has-to-string-tag-x@1.4.0 checking installable status
112 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/has-symbol-support-x 184ms (from cache)
113 silly pacote range manifest for has-symbol-support-x@^1.4.0 fetched in 184ms
114 silly resolveWithNewModule has-symbol-support-x@1.4.0 checking installable status
115 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/is-primitive 179ms (from cache)
116 silly pacote range manifest for is-primitive@^2.0.0 fetched in 184ms
117 silly resolveWithNewModule is-primitive@2.0.0 checking installable status
118 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/is-function-x 204ms (from cache)
119 silly pacote range manifest for is-function-x@^1.4.0 fetched in 219ms
120 silly resolveWithNewModule is-function-x@1.4.0 checking installable status
121 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash.isnull 179ms (from cache)
122 silly pacote range manifest for lodash.isnull@^3.0.0 fetched in 184ms
123 silly resolveWithNewModule lodash.isnull@3.0.0 checking installable status
124 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/validate.io-undefined 204ms (from cache)
125 silly pacote range manifest for validate.io-undefined@^1.0.3 fetched in 209ms
126 silly resolveWithNewModule validate.io-undefined@1.0.3 checking installable status
127 silly pacote range manifest for readable-stream@~1.1.9 fetched in 15ms
128 silly resolveWithNewModule readable-stream@1.1.14 checking installable status
129 silly pacote version manifest for isarray@0.0.1 fetched in 15ms
130 silly resolveWithNewModule isarray@0.0.1 checking installable status
131 silly pacote range manifest for string_decoder@~0.10.x fetched in 15ms
132 silly resolveWithNewModule string_decoder@0.10.31 checking installable status
133 silly pacote range manifest for readable-stream@>=1.0.33-1 <1.1.0-0 fetched in 25ms
134 silly resolveWithNewModule readable-stream@1.0.34 checking installable status
135 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/xtend 249ms (from cache)
136 silly pacote range manifest for xtend@>=4.0.0 <4.1.0-0 fetched in 253ms
137 silly resolveWithNewModule xtend@4.0.1 checking installable status
138 silly pacote version manifest for isarray@0.0.1 fetched in 5ms
139 silly resolveWithNewModule isarray@0.0.1 checking installable status
140 silly pacote range manifest for string_decoder@~0.10.x fetched in 5ms
141 silly resolveWithNewModule string_decoder@0.10.31 checking installable status
142 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/glob 329ms (from cache)
143 silly pacote range manifest for glob@^7.0.5 fetched in 337ms
144 silly resolveWithNewModule glob@7.1.2 checking installable status
145 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/fs.realpath 273ms (from cache)
146 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/inflight 273ms (from cache)
147 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/once 272ms (from cache)
148 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/path-is-absolute 272ms (from cache)
149 silly pacote range manifest for fs.realpath@^1.0.0 fetched in 283ms
150 silly resolveWithNewModule fs.realpath@1.0.0 checking installable status
151 silly pacote range manifest for inflight@^1.0.4 fetched in 283ms
152 silly resolveWithNewModule inflight@1.0.6 checking installable status
153 silly pacote range manifest for once@^1.3.0 fetched in 278ms
154 silly resolveWithNewModule once@1.4.0 checking installable status
155 silly pacote range manifest for path-is-absolute@^1.0.0 fetched in 282ms
156 silly resolveWithNewModule path-is-absolute@1.0.1 checking installable status
157 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/minimatch 288ms (from cache)
158 silly pacote range manifest for minimatch@^3.0.4 fetched in 288ms
159 silly resolveWithNewModule minimatch@3.0.4 checking installable status
160 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/wrappy 185ms (from cache)
161 silly pacote range manifest for wrappy@1 fetched in 185ms
162 silly resolveWithNewModule wrappy@1.0.2 checking installable status
163 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/brace-expansion 187ms (from cache)
164 silly pacote range manifest for brace-expansion@^1.1.7 fetched in 192ms
165 silly resolveWithNewModule brace-expansion@1.1.8 checking installable status
166 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/balanced-match 204ms (from cache)
167 silly pacote range manifest for balanced-match@^1.0.0 fetched in 209ms
168 silly resolveWithNewModule balanced-match@1.0.0 checking installable status
169 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/concat-map 209ms (from cache)
170 silly pacote version manifest for concat-map@0.0.1 fetched in 214ms
171 silly resolveWithNewModule concat-map@0.0.1 checking installable status
172 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/chalk 185ms (from cache)
173 silly pacote range manifest for chalk@^1.1.3 fetched in 195ms
174 silly resolveWithNewModule chalk@1.1.3 checking installable status
175 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/split 225ms (from cache)
176 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/latest-version 225ms (from cache)
177 silly pacote range manifest for split@^1.0.0 fetched in 225ms
178 silly resolveWithNewModule split@1.0.0 checking installable status
179 silly pacote range manifest for latest-version@^3.0.0 fetched in 230ms
180 silly resolveWithNewModule latest-version@3.1.0 checking installable status
181 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/combined-stream-wait-for-it 429ms (from cache)
182 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/simple-terminal-menu 429ms (from cache)
183 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/i18n-core 429ms (from cache)
184 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/string-to-stream 429ms (from cache)
185 silly pacote range manifest for combined-stream-wait-for-it@^1.1.0 fetched in 434ms
186 silly resolveWithNewModule combined-stream-wait-for-it@1.1.0 checking installable status
187 silly pacote range manifest for i18n-core@^3.0.0 fetched in 444ms
188 silly resolveWithNewModule i18n-core@3.2.0 checking installable status
189 silly pacote range manifest for simple-terminal-menu@^1.1.3 fetched in 449ms
190 silly resolveWithNewModule simple-terminal-menu@1.1.3 checking installable status
191 silly pacote range manifest for string-to-stream@^1.1.0 fetched in 489ms
192 silly resolveWithNewModule string-to-stream@1.1.0 checking installable status
193 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/commandico 494ms (from cache)
194 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/msee 494ms (from cache)
195 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/workshopper-adventure-storage 489ms (from cache)
196 silly pacote range manifest for commandico@^2.0.2 fetched in 494ms
197 silly resolveWithNewModule commandico@2.0.2 checking installable status
198 silly pacote range manifest for msee@^0.3.2 fetched in 498ms
199 silly resolveWithNewModule msee@0.3.3 checking installable status
200 silly pacote range manifest for workshopper-adventure-storage@^3.0.0 fetched in 502ms
201 silly resolveWithNewModule workshopper-adventure-storage@3.0.0 checking installable status
202 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for codeclimate-test-reporter@github:codeclimate/javascript-test-reporter#97f1ff2cf18cd5f03191d3d53e671c47e954f2fa Error while executing:
202 silly fetchPackageMetaData C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.EXE ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/codeclimate/javascript-test-reporter.git
202 silly fetchPackageMetaData
202 silly fetchPackageMetaData
202 silly fetchPackageMetaData exited with error code: 3221225781
203 verbose stack Error: exited with error code: 3221225781
203 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.onexit (C:\Users\Abhinav\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\mississippi\node_modules\end-of-stream\index.js:39:36)
203 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
203 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
203 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:215:12)
204 verbose cwd C:\Users\Abhinav
205 verbose Windows_NT 6.3.9600
206 verbose argv "C:\\Users\\Abhinav\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\node\\bin\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Abhinav\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "learnyounode"
207 verbose node v6.11.1
208 verbose npm  v5.3.0
209 error Error while executing:
209 error C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.EXE ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/codeclimate/javascript-test-reporter.git
209 error
209 error
209 error exited with error code: 3221225781
210 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: What does `2017-07-26T08_28_33_282Z-debug.log` says?

Comment: Can you `git clone git@github.com/codeclimate/javascript-test-reporter.git`?

Comment: `C:\Users\Abhinav\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-07-26T08_28_3
3_282Z-debug.log` will tell you more. You might have to reinstall node or add it to the path variables. Have you been able to `npm install` anything?

Comment: @admcfajn Hi, i tried reinstalling node but it didn't work, yes i did install few modules before using `npm install`. 
@onetwo12 Hi, sorry but since  i am new to all this,  am unable to understand what `2017-07-26T08_28_33_282Z-debug.log`. is trying to convey.

Comment: If `2017-07-26T08_28_33_282Z-debug.log` is not very big can you post it in the question.

Comment: Have you set up git public key? and again, can you execute `git clone git@github.com/codeclimate/javascript-test-reporter.git`

Comment: @onetwo12 No, i can't execute `git clone git@github.com/codeclimate/javascript-test-reporter.git`, my system throws an error `The program cannot start because libivconv-2.dll is missing from your computer.`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3431361/git-for-windows-the-program-cant-start-because-libiconv2-dll-is-missing

Comment: @onetwo12: No do not have the git public key? Actually, I dont have any idea about it at the first place.Could you help me out? 
Thanks