# MSysGit vs. Git for Windows

Tags: windows, git, msysgit

I am having trouble determining the [difference between MSysGit and Git for Windows](http://msysgit.github.com/). How are they different? Why would I choose one over the other?

Comment: +1, this is actually a harder/more involved/important question than it first appears.

Comment: See also Different between msysgit and cygwin + git ?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144082/different-between-msysgit-and-cygwin-git/3144417#3144417

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/22310007/405017 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/11849737/405017 and http://superuser.com/q/742536

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Are they not the same thing?

On: http://msysgit.github.com/ The title is Git for Windows, the application is msysgit.

Even in the event they are not, I expect the only differences will be in the method of compilation (i.e. compiler used and any options set) and any extraneous packaging (such as having a bash emulating shell as in msysgit). The actual product (Git itself) should remain broadly similar.

---

**Edit**: Thanks to Jarrod for pointing this out. I've left the above in for posterity. To quote the wiki:

> msysGit is the development environment
>   to compile Git for Windows. It is
>   complete, in the sense that you just
>   need to install msysGit, and then you
>   can build Git. Without installing any
>   3rd-party software.
>   msysGit is not Git for Windows; that
>   is an installer which installs Git --
>   and only Git.
>
> It is easy to see the difference: the
>   installers for Git have the prefix
>   Git-, the msysGit installers have the
>   prefix msysGit-. Another telltale is
>   that the msysGit installers come in
>   two flavors: fullinstall and
>   netinstall. Further, msysGit does not
>   install to C:\Program Files by
>   default. But msysGit comes with gcc,
>   the GNU C Compiler.

So, [the difference between the two projects](http://msysgit.github.com/):

- **msysGit** is the `msys`+`mingw` environment + everything needed to compile Git yourself, on Windows.
- **Git for Windows** is exactly that: Git, compiled for Windows.

Comment: I don't think they are the same thing.  If you follow a link in the one you posted, you will find "msysGit is not Git for Windows" on the wiki

Comment: @Jarrod I think you are absolutely correct and I've updated my answer.

Comment: Please excuse my ignorance, but why would I want to compile git?  If I just wanted to use git for source control on windows, do I need msysGit?

Comment: @Jarrod I don't know... because a usual approach would be to install msys or such-like. I expect for whatever reason they found they had to set the environment up in a certain way, so they packaged it.

Comment: @Jarrod Short answer to your question: No. Get Git on Windows.

Comment: @Jarrod: You'd want to compile it yourself if you wanted to use the latest version of git, so you can get all the exciting new features as soon as possible! I do this on linux.

Comment: @Jefromi: so that is the only reason I would want MsysGit?

Comment: @Jarrod: For you, yes. Other reasons: you want to control how it's compiled for some reason, you want to hack on the source code...

Comment: MsysGit will also get you a rudimentary unix shell environment as an alternative to Cygwin...

Comment: An important practical difference is that msysGit comes with "git bash"(MSYS). This is a bash shell that runs on windows - and it works great. You don't have to use this bash shell for git related stuff, but you can. It's nice to be able to use grep and sed and other nice unix commands.

Comment: Why keep the wrong info for posterity? Who cares that you were wrong initially?

Comment: There is no reason to leave the original version. I think this answer should be updated to reflect the best knowledge (and delete the incorrect knowledge).

Answer (score 16):

**(Now) they are the same** (as of May 2015 but likely a bit earlier):

"msysgit" and "Git for Windows" have merged under the name "Git for Windows." [msysgit.github.io](http://msysgit.github.io) now hosts "Git for Windows" and the main git download site [git-scm.com](http://git-scm.com/download/win) lists [msysgit.github.io](http://msysgit.github.io) as the maintained build for windows.

From the updated [wiki](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/wiki/Relationship-to-Git-for-Windows):

> ...  we decided to just phase out the name "msysGit" (as well as the GitHub org of the same name) and work on Git for Windows (with the corresponding GitHub org, and using the name "Git for Windows" for the installer aimed at "end-users" and "Git for Windows SDK" for the development environment targeting Git for Windows developers).

Comment: How can they be the same, when git-for-windows is a fork of msysgit, git-for-windows is hard under development and msysgit is not, and git-for-windows uses Git 2.4?

Comment: @BlackEye. Sounds like an interesting history. My answer was just pointing out that these projects have *now* merged (as described on the project wiki), despite their history. Seems this is relevant for many people trying to sort out which one to use now.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the excerpt 'Official README'

"portable" version of Git for Windows (MSysGit) does not need tobe installed. It will run from any directory you place it in, evenonto a USB thumbdrive. It will not write permanent entries into the Windows registry. It does not need administrator privileges to "install". This version does not offer you the convenient right-click context menu entries "Git GUI Here" and "Git Bash Here", because these would require to add entries into the Windows registry.

Comment: That applies to both of them I think.

Answer (score 4):

[Git for Windows](http://git-for-windows.github.io/) is newer than [msysGit](https://msysgit.github.io/). If you want to use Git version 2.x you need to download from https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases. https://github.com/msysgit/git/releases is used for Git version 1.x.

Some technical details from https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/wiki/FAQ

> Git for Windows used to be developed using the development environment called "msysGit", but roughly coinciding with Git 2.1, msysGit was superseded by a new development environment: the [Git for Windows SDK](https://github.com/git-for-windows/sdk).

Answer (score 3):

As many answers in this post are old.

As on Nov 2015,

[msysGit](https://github.com/msysgit/git)-based Git for Windows 1.x is now superseded by Git for Windows 2.x.

[Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) and [git-scm](https://git-scm.com/downloads/win) both points to same download location for their binary

**Download Location:**

https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.7.1.windows.2/Git-2.7.1.2-64-bit.exe

Answer (score 2):

The titles on the download page have just been updated so that the "Git for Windows" versions are fully identified. There is now both an 'installed' version (with right click menu options), and a Portable version that runs direct from a memory stick etc.

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand **Git on Windows** is the project consisting of the four bulletpoints below.

Taken directly from https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/wiki:

**Git on Windows**

To make the milky 'soup' of project names more clear, we say like this:

- **msysGit** - is the name of this project, a build environment for Git
  for Windows, which releases the official binaries
- **MinGW** - is a minimalist development environment for native Microsoft Windows applications.
- **MSYS** - is a Bourne Shell command line interpreter system, is used by MinGW (and others), was forked *in the past* from Cygwin
- **Cygwin** - a Linux like environment, which was used in the past to build Git for Windows, nowadays has no relation to msysGit

Comment: Isn't there one bullet missing: "git for windows"?  What the average Windows GIT user installs to use GIT.  https://github.com/msysgit/git

Answer (score 1):

This is a more clear general comparison right from their site https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit

```
Git for Windows is the software package that installs a minimal environment to run Git on Windows. It comes with a Bash (a Unix-type shell), with a Perl interpreter and with the Git executable and its dependencies.

On the other hand, msysGit is the software package installing the build environment that can build Git for Windows. The easiest way is to install it via the net installer.
```

Answer (score 1):

[Git for Windows](https://msysgit.github.io) is probably what you want.  It includes the following primary features:

> **Git BASH** Git for Windows provides a BASH emulation used to run Git
>   from the command line. *NIX users should feel right at home, as the
>   BASH emulation behaves just like the "git" command in LINUX and UNIX
>   environments.
>
> **Git GUI** As Windows users commonly expect graphical user
>   interfaces, Git for Windows also provides the Git GUI, a powerful
>   alternative to Git BASH, offering a graphical version of just about
>   every Git command line function, as well as comprehensive visual diff
>   tools.
>
> **Shell Integration** Simply right-click on a folder in Windows
>   Explorer to access the BASH or GUI. The Git-Cheetah plugin also
>   provides a TortoiseSVN-like interface that displays Git functions
>   directly on the context menu.

The following is available as a separate download from the same page...

> **msysGit** is a build environment that includes all the tools necessary for developers who want to contribute by writing code for Git for Windows.

---

Git BASH delivers a familiar environment for Linux experts who occasionally need to use a Windows machine -- even if they don't need `git` itself.  It starts with the BASH prompt and adds a collection of core utility programs such as `ssh`, `find`, `grep`, `vi`, `awk`, and of course `git`.

Comment: [Integrating the Git bash into Console](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2010/04/05/integrating-the-git-bash-into-console)

Comment: By now, you might be more interested in [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux).