# Git rebase got 'unlink of file failed' error

Tags: git

Using **msysgit 1.7.0.2**, when doing `git rebase -i`, it hangs and there's no message.
After enter <kbd>ctrl+c</kbd>, I can see

```
'unlink of file failed, should I try again (y/n)?'
```

Then I tried `git rebase --abort` but got same error message. So now it's stuck in the middle of rebase process. This error seems to be caused by read-only file.

Is there any way to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Did you try with `set GIT_ASK_YESNO=false`?

This [Google group thread](http://groups.google.com/group/msysgit/browse_thread/thread/5367e417693a77c0) mentions it in the recent mingw evolutions:

> Make use of the new environment variable `GIT_ASK_YESNO` to support the recently implemented fallback in case `unlink`, `rename` or `rmdir` fail for files in use on Windows.

What exact version of Git for windows are you using?
Note: [msysgit setup is not the same than the "Git for Windows" setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3672272/msysgit-vs-git-for-windows), see also "[Different between msysgit and cygwin + git ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144082/different-between-msysgit-and-cygwin-git/3144417#3144417)")

---

[git 2.8.4 (June 2016)](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/tag/v2.8.4.windows.1) does mention [issue 755](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/pull/755) which should also alleviate the issue ([commit 2db0641](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/commit/2db0641fa2c7ff0ae2521b7045634cfd6d69d70d)):

> ### Make sure temporary file handles are not inherited by child processes

---

See also Git 2.19 (Q3 2018): "[Git - Unlink of file .idx and .pack failed (The only process owned handle to this file is git.exe)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51755262/6309)".

Comment: If you set GIT_ASK_YESNO to false, what will it answer? yes or no?

Comment: @KlasMellbourn I believe the idea is to avoid git asking anything.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if it applies in your situation, but I've just had a similar situation with 1.7.10.msysgit.1 (talking to a network share on an Ubuntu server). In my case, a failed merge had made several objects owned by root with permissions -r--rwSr--. A simple SSH login and

```
sudo chown steve: .git/*
```

fixed one problem (for my user - unless you're called steve, you'll need to change that to your username!), and

```
chmod -R 0755 .git/*
```

fixed the other.

Comment: I was running on windows, without administrator privileges. After running the command prompt with privileges it worked. So... I got something from your anser!

Answer (score 1):

There might be an instance of the file that causes the error to pop-up in git, try closing all other instances of the file and then pressing "y" in git.

Hope it solves the issue!