# Unlink of file Failed. Should I try again?

Tags: git, unlink

Something wrong is going on with one of the files in my local git repository. When I'm trying to change the branch it says:

```
Unlink of file 'templates/media/container.html' failed. Should I try again? (y/n)
```

What could that mean?

Comment: Check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3698369/285619)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git rebase got 'unlink of file failed' error ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698369/git-rebase-got-unlink-of-file-failed-error)

Comment: did the given answer work for you, if process viewer is not working then restart and you can then remove file, also you can accept the answer if it worked for you

Comment: Also check that the git process has write permissions on that file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unlink of file failed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10181057/unlink-of-file-failed)

Comment: Git 2.19 should improve the situation, at least on Windows: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51755262/6309

Comment: Given that this now shows as the first result on a Google search, and the question and the answers here have gotten > 10x more views and upvotes than the other questions linked above, I would venture that this has now become the de-facto reference QA for the "unlink of file" failed question.

Comment: Git 2.29 (Q4 2020) might improve the situation. See [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63662344/6309).

Answer (score 1147, accepted):

This could mean that another program is using the file, which is preventing git from "moving" the file into or out of the working directory when you are attempting to change branches.

I have had this happen on Windows Vista where eclipse is the program "using" the file. The file may not be actually open in eclipse but may have been opened by a process run by eclipse.

In this event, try closing the file in any applications that might have used it. If that doesn't work, completely exit any applications which may have opened the file.

Comment: On Windows, use ProcessExplorer to find which process has the file open.

Comment: Is there a way to write a script like "if this file cannot be deleted (e.g. the file just does not exists), just skip the file".

Comment: +1 @DaveC. I searched in vain for ProcessExplorer in my tools and then downloaded https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx

Comment: @BBrown That's the ProcessExplorer I was talking about. You found the official link for downloading it.

Comment: In my case that was Visual Studio and its Git plugin.

Comment: thanks @dave-c, use Process Explorer Search (Process Explorer > ctrl + F > file name) find PID using your file and kill it

Comment: Whenever I switch to another branch immediately after I stop the project from running, I get the same error and all I do is close Visual Studio and click on "Yes" to try again and it works.

Comment: In Windows 10: I have to kill git processes running from Task-Manager(Ctrl + Shift + Esc), to do away with `Unlink of file Failed` issue.

Comment: This is very inconvenient if you've opened a terminal *inside* your IDE (IntelliJ IDEA in my case) and the IDE is the program that's using the file.

Comment: The process locking the file in my case is `git.exe`. This is also the process being blocked by the file being locked (silly). I guess when it's finished it might unlock the files, and I can delete them, or something, but the problem is that the `git svn clone` has been running for a week now, and it's stopping the process when it hits a locked file... annoying...

Comment: On Windows, if you don't have ProcessExplorer available or don't want to download it, you can run (Windows + R) "resmon", go to the CPU tab and search the file name in the "Associated Identifiers" textbox.

Comment: @Raphael I think you probably may have referred to "Associated Handles" in the CPU tab of Resource Monitor on Windows 10. Apart from that in my case the file in question was not listed and I still had the problem. To resolve it I simply restarted File Explorer which by the looks still had a handle on it without showing up in the "Associated Handles" list.

Comment: TY in my case I only needed close jaspersoft report to work it you clarify what was happening

Comment: @Manfred Yes, "Associated Handles". The other was a mistranslation on my part. :)

Comment: If you use `GitKraken` you might get this if you perform commands like a rebase

Comment: In my case it was the explorer.exe itself which i had to restart. Thanks Dave for the tip with the ProcessExplorer

Comment: The problem occurs for me when GitKraken is opened.

Comment: Thanks. if anybody gets this problem try to close on program opening. My case is on window system.

Comment: Having to close VS every time I need to change a branch is a little bit insane isn't it?

Comment: Thanks. I only needed the "This could mean that another program is using the file", meaning it is still running.

Comment: In my case I had two instances of the Windows terminal open. One was running the Python application I was working on. I just closed it. Thanks.

Comment: Answer is spot on. In my case it was a jar file that was stuck and my server was up and running and using that jar file. Shutting down the server worked

Comment: In my case it was MATLAB which was using the file even though the file was not opened. By closing the MATLAB and executing a force checkout `git checkout -f master` solved my issue.

Comment: For my case in Windows, the files that was not able to unlink had other access rights (admin) and the only why to solve it, was to manually delete them in Explorer (given the admin rights at given point). Then during pull re-create those again.

Comment: I had to do a full reboot of Windows for Windows to release the file. I closed everything and could not figure out why Windows still had the .git files locked. One more reason to switch to Linux, as Linux doesn't do this...

Comment: How to use and find the Resource Monitor / Process Explorer, which others are mentioning in the comments: [Super User: Find out which process is locking a file or folder in Windows](https://superuser.com/a/643312/425838)

Answer (score 365):

I had this issue and solved it by the command : `git gc`
The above command remove temp and unnecessary files. (Garbage collector.)

Comment: `git pull` initiated `git gc` automatically, and gc tried to access some .pack and .inx files. These were hold by "windows git" process, that owned `git pull` command. Running `git gc` manually and than - `git pull` really resolves the issue.

Comment: While running `git gc` i got the same error again when `gc` was in progress

Comment: "Running git gc manually and than - git pull really resolves the issue." This helped. Thank you Nikita.

Comment: This helped me as well. Ran this on Windows with Git Bash

Comment: After starting the git pull I got this error. I pressed CTRL+C to stop the pull, run the git gc and then git pull again, the problem had disappeared and nothing was broken by interrupting the pull.

Comment: Ran this command because I was trying to revert a commit using `git reset --hard HEAD^` and worked out perfectly.

Comment: What worked for me was to run git bash as an administrator and run git pull

Answer (score 114):

this solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12280076/184176) worked for me:

> This is a Windows specific answer, so I'm aware that it's not relevant to you... I'm just including it for the benefit of future searchers.
>
> In my case, it was because I was running Git from a non-elevated command line. "Run as Administrator" fixed it for me.

Comment: Worked for me. Ran VS as admin and then launched the command prompt from VS

Comment: I: typed `Ctrl+C` to terminate the very long list of unlinkable files; exited gitbash, my IDE, and the GitHub Windows application; restarted gitbash in elevated "Run as Administrator" mode; and ran `git gc --aggressive`. Took a while to complete, but made it through with no errors.

Comment: If you believe this is a duplicate you should flag it as such, not add an answer that points to another answer

Comment: @Liam This question is older but this answer was only on the other question, and there isn't only one answer to this question which makes it harder to just set one as duplicate.

Comment: This worked pretty well for me. None of the previous answer did. Thanks a lot.

Comment: worked for me! i just had to open the terminal with run as ADMIN and then the unlink file problems stopped

Answer (score 47):

I encountered this issue while doing a `git pull`.

I tried `git gc` and it resolved my problem.

Comment: I ran into this issue on Windows machine and this solution didn't initially work. However once I ran this command from an admin command prompt it did resolve my issue.

Answer (score 28):

In my case there are no processes touching the file or directory. Maybe it happens if the path is very long, because an operating system restriction (windows). Try enabling the longpath support flag in the global git configuration as indicated below:

```
git config --global core.longpaths true
```

or try to setting the yes/no answer flag if it is not conflictive for you

```
set GIT_ASK_YESNO=false
```

If the path is too long, I've not found a successful solution.

Comment: I do not know why but setting "git config --global core.longpaths true" was helpful for me.

Comment: `GIT_ASK_YESNO`, can't find info about this one. Where does it come from ?

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698369/git-rebase-got-unlink-of-file-failed-error for example; I don't now if it works with recents versions of  git  (2.9)

Comment: `core.longpaths` with additional:
reset --hard
prune
gc

worked for me - but had to close AndroidStudio to not mess up with its build in tools

Answer (score 20):

This might be useful for someone; if all the above didn't work for you, follow these steps:

1. Close your IDE (mine was Eclipse, not sure if it applies to Intellij and others) or any other app that might be using git.
2. Open git from the command line (in my case I had git bash) and run `git gc` as mentioned by others.

This did the magic for me.

Comment: This is the only answer that helped in my case, using Android Studio

Answer (score 16):

As i am using [gitkraken](https://www.gitkraken.com/download) and command prompt,  i ran into the same issue. And then i run  `git gc` command it resolved my problem. So i am happy and want share some of the points which might be helpful.

**What `git gc` will do ?**

**`git gc`** removing unreachable objects which may have been created from prior invocations of git add.

When to run `git gc`?

From [doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc), users are encouraged to run this task on a regular basis within each repository to maintain good disk space utilization and good operating performance.

**How to make it auto-configurable?**

Some git commands may automatically run git gc; see the --auto flag below for details. If you know what you’re doing and all you want is to disable this behavior permanently without further considerations, just do

```
git config --global gc.auto 0
```

Comment: I closed gitkraken and my external git command line windows, then executed `git gc`, and everything appears to be back to normal.

Answer (score 12):

I had this kind of issue on Windows 7 and it turned out to be due to some orphaned `git.exe` process.

To solve it, open Task Manager and kill all `git.exe` processes.

Since `git` commands are short-lived, you should normally never see any `git.exe` in Task Manager. When they are there, it usually means something is wrong, and you should kill those processes.

Answer (score 11):

I tried `git gc` and it resolved my problem.

Answer (score 10):

On Windows 8:
I ran `git gc` and it said `git gc` was already running, I ran `git gc --force` and the garbage collector ran.

I could then switch branches and merge without any issues, try `git gc --force`.

Perhaps the `gc` process didn't stop gracefully for one reason or another.

Comment: It is also valid for Windows 10.

Comment: Even with force the issue persists

Answer (score 9):

I got this problem in Windows. I closed my IDE (Android Studio) and selected YES in git shell. It worked.

Answer (score 9):

I was able to solve this by **opening Powershell as Administrator** and from there 
`git checkout <branch_name>`

Comment: Thanks @bar-horing. This helped me identify it as a permission issue. Once I fixed the windows permission for that folder it worked.

Comment: Me too, run cmd as administrator on Win Server 16 :)

Answer (score 8):

In my case (Win8.1, TortoiseGit running), it was the process called "TortoiseSVN status cache" that was locking the file.

Killing it allowed me to run "git gc" without any more problems.
The above process is fired up by TortoiseGit, so there is no need to manually restart it.

Answer (score 4):

I had this issue with `.tmp` files in `/.git/objects/pack` folder. I think something had failed during a push or pull, so I removed these temporary files and reset the HEAD to my last commit. Not sure if this is advised but it worked for me. Also `git count-objects -v` gave me a list of the `.tmp` files that didn't belong in the pack folder.

Or to suppress the y/n messages in windows `git open cmd.exe` and run:

```
SETX GIT_ASK_YESNO false
```

seen here: https://twitter.com/petercamfield/status/494805475733807104

Comment: After having run `git gc`, `git count-objects -v` helps in identifying leftover temp objects in the `pack` folder.

Answer (score 4):

I faced same issue while doing 'git pull'. I tried manual housekeeping git command 'git gc' and it resolved my problem.

Comment: While this **is** an attempt at an answer, it doesn't add anything that isn't already covered by other answers (such as [this one](//stackoverflow.com/a/26229658/2747593)). If you are trying to confirm that this solution works, or wish to thank the author of that answer, please do not post an answer to do so. After you gain some more [reputation](//stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will gain sufficient [privileges](//stackoverflow.com/privileges) to [upvote](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-up) answers you like, which is the Stack Overflow way of saying thank you.

Comment: **Flaggers / reviewers:** [For duplicate answers such as this one, downvote and/or flag for moderator attention, don't delete!](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/310097/2747593)

Answer (score 3):

After trying various solutions finally `git clean -f` helped me.

EDIT: I hit the problem again few times - closing all processes dependent on git seems to help (like gitbash, Eclipse IDE, etc.)

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this issue in Windows, you might want to run the git bash as an administrator and then perform the desire commands, that solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 3):

After run command

```
git rm -rf foo.bar
```

I see error

```
Unlink of file 'foo.bar' failed. Should I try again? (y/n)
```

Because **another program is using this file**. For example, when I run Java web application in debug model or run web application on server, I can't delete log file. Turn off application sever (or turn off debug process), re-try

```
git rm -rf foo.bar
```

I see file has been deleted.

Answer (score 3):

Worked for me, Tried on windows:

**Stop your server** running from IDE or close your IDE

Intellij/Ecllipse or any, it will work.

Answer (score 3):

if your os host is linux/unix-like, you can run `git gc --force` to stop the file handler which take use of git files,

else if you're working on windows, you can stop git process by Task Manager or Process Manager. It seems that there are another git process taking use of your git files. Just kill the git process

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this issue running git Bash and Eclipse EGit at the same time.
Solution: close Eclipse. Also wouldn't hurt to run `git gc` as @khilo mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

As stated above, something else is holding the files. Thing is that program doesnt look suspicious for us. 
I was trying to do a git pull from console, while having GitKraken opened. Closing GitKraken fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Docker and running Windows 10, you may want to stop the container(s) where the file may be running at. To show the statuses of your containers, run

`docker ps -a`

To stop them, simply run

`docker stop <container name or container id>`

This worked for me as I am running my local files using a .sh file

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I was trying to run `git fetch --all` from within GitKraken's terminal. I had to close Gitkraken and run the command from Windows Terminal in order for it to work.

Comment: This was exactly my issue as well. After closing GitKracken the `gc` that `git` was trying to run was successful.

Answer (score 1):

After none of the above answers seemed to work, running `git fetch -p` did the job for me.

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch

Answer (score 1):

I tried every single tip on this page and nothing helped. I was doing a `git fetch` and a `git reset --hard origin/development` gave me the unkink error. I couldn't reset to the latest commit.

What helped was checking out another branch and then checking out the previous branch. Very strange but it solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If closing your IDE and running various git commands listed here won't help, try manually killing all running Java processes. I had a Java process probably left over from eclipse that somehow kept a configuration file open.

Answer (score 1):

For my Spring Boot project I ran into this errror when attempting to run `git stash`.

The solution was to killed all of the Java processes running on my machine.

Answer (score 1):

In my situation the cause was that I had ran Visual Studio as an administrator earlier in the day. When I went to switch branches the error occurred.

I use GitExtensions and I run it as a regular users and files created by VS while running as an administrator ( run as Administrator, still me though) were not accessible. This was the root of the cause for me. I'm not sure why it happened in this situation because I regularly run VS as administrator on my primary development environment and have not experienced this problem before. But for some reason today the above scenario caused any files generated by VS during that session to be un-editable...you can read them, but not change or delete them and that is exactly what Git is going to do when you switch branches.

To resolve the problem for Git I had to start windows explorer as administrator and take ownership and re give myself permissions to files and directories in question. I don't fully understand why this as I was running explorer as Administrator too but it did.

You can do this for the files individually but I ended up doing this process for the root folder of the branch.

So the exact steps I did to fix the problem are:
Went to the top of the branch in windows explorer, 
right clicked properties of the directory, 
select the security tab, 
advanced options which opens the Advanced Security Settings dialog,
Selected change ownership at the top  (it might show you already own it), 
I re-selected myself.
Then it returns you to the 'Advanced Security Settings' dialog, at the bottom of remember to check the box 'Replace all object...'
Then click apply
The system cycles through each file and folder fixing ownership and that resolved the problem for me.

For me it had locked out my migrations folder and wouldn't let me switch branches...so I originally just fixed that directory and sub tree which allowed me to switch branches but I had closed VS trying to resolved the issue.  When I reopened VS I did not run VS as the Administrator and I found that could not compile the solution now!  It was the same\similar issue. It could not compile the solution as all of the obj directories were now non editable... so that is when I did the above steps and all was good again.

Hope this helps someone... ;)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the above answers, yes file must be used maybe by other java processes, simple way to get rid-off this is, just kill all java processes then execute `git pull` I did this, it works for me.

For windows kill all java processes:

```
taskkill /F /IM java.exe
```

For Linux kill all java processes:

```
kill -9 `pidof java`
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be a separate gitk window running to see some git history.

Just close that window to fix that problem.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, saw this error on a `git clone` of a (fairly large) repo. Closed [SmartGit](https://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/) and paused my backup software (CrashPlan), and after that it worked. Not sure which of the 2 did the trick, but if running either, this might do it for you too.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while doing a git pull and as stated above, it was because of a program that was holding those files and was not allowing a git pull. Closing the program helped. Usually, the IDE (like Eclipse) from where the files are being checked-in will be holding it in the background. Closing the same and re-running git pull solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error and closing the app which had the file open solved it.  I was able to go back and press "Y"

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing a web application, a common reason is to forget shutting down the server. For example this could be a simple Node.js process, or on windows your IIS process running more unobtrusive as background process.

Answer (score 0):

in my case there was a copy or replace window for that particular file open and hence the unlink error. i closed it and there is no unlink error

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by restarting PHPStorm (insert your programm instead) as administrator

Answer (score 0):

You might see that error less often with Git 2.29 (Q4 2020): the "unlink" emulation on MinGW has been optimized.

See [commit 680e0b4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/680e0b4524482c4bb679030188f6ae8db4caff06) (17 Aug 2020) by [Jeff Hostetler (`Jeff-Hostetler`)](https://github.com/Jeff-Hostetler).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 5a04826](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5a0482662f076ca7e1f27ef2848feec1763583d1), 19 Aug 2020)</sup>

> ### [`mingw`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/680e0b4524482c4bb679030188f6ae8db4caff06): improve performance of `mingw_unlink()`
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jeff Hostetler</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Johannes Schindelin</sup>

> Update `mingw_unlink()` to first try to delete the file with existing permissions before trying to force it.
>
> Windows throws an error when trying to delete a read-only file.
> The `mingw_unlink()` compatibility wrapper always tries to `_wchmod(`666) the file before calling `_wunlink()` to avoid that error.
> However, since most files in the worktree are already writable, this is usually wasted effort.
>
> Update `mingw_unlink()` to just call `DeleteFileW()` directly and if that succeeds return.
> If that fails, fall back into the existing code path to update the permissions and use `_wunlink()` to get the existing error code mapping.

Comment: I'm on 2.30.1.windows.1 and I still get this a lot.

Comment: @harvzor Are you using the Git for Windows or Git through a WSL2 Linux session?

Comment: Typing `where git` returns `C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe` so I'm pretty sure it's Windows, that's probably why the version also has "windows" in it. I had VS Code open when I used git so likely the top rated answer is correct in regards to Code locking the files up.

Comment: @harvzor I agree, especially considering that VSCode auto-fetch Git repositories (https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/40282)

Answer (score 0):

For me I had to go in my .git folder and delete index.lock file.
After that, I can undo as usual.