# git pull causing "unlink of file failed" error

Tags: git

I'm trying to do a `git pull` and am running into the dreaded "unlink of file xxx failed" error.

I've tried ProcessExplorer as defined in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6076796/341611) answer; using the find function doesn't return any process using the file in question.

I've also tried running `git gc` as mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26229658/341611) answer, and it runs, but I still get the error.

I have write permissions to the file in question.

Any other suggestions? This is causing a major problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unlink of file Failed. Should I try again?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389833/unlink-of-file-failed-should-i-try-again)

Answer (score 2):

That should be fixed in Git 2.8 (March 2016)

See [commit d562102](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d5621020c1e0edfa998cb5c5e80cdf47f36ffb1a), [commit dcacb1b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/dcacb1b2ee42d3cc20e4720134f18ab5ba267f3a), [commit df617b5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/df617b529e9ebf01cde572b8f78f4dd8bc6c010b), [commit 0898c96](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0898c96281044a1130f1a777660aaf17e782c4f6) (13 Jan 2016) by [Johannes Schindelin (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 3c80940](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3c809405cb35679dd5205bf0ea118b7ee9256abb), 26 Jan 2016)</sup>

> ### `fetch`: release pack files before garbage-collecting
>
> Before auto-gc'ing, we need to make sure that the pack files are released in case they need to be repacked and garbage-collected.
>
> Many codepaths that run "`gc --auto`" before exiting kept packfiles mapped and left the file descriptors to them open, which was not friendly to systems that cannot remove files that are open.
> They now close the packs before doing so.

That fixes [`git-for-widows` issue 500](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/500).

Looking at the [test used to validate that new approach](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0898c96281044a1130f1a777660aaf17e782c4f6#diff-460c7b28c3b4d83da23f72d403d06b70R719), maybe you can (since Git 2.8 is not yet out) raise artificially `gc.autoPackLimit`.

```
git config gc.autoPackLimit 10000
git fetch
git config gc.autoPackLimit 50 # default value
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the cmd ?
If yes try git pull after switching to git-bash(run the bash.exe file in the GIT directory bin folder) which should not have any problem (the error related to Windows) and the git-bash is UNIX.

Comment: Nope, using git bash.

Answer (score 0):

I just had that issue and also tried running `git gc` and made sure no process was using the files affected by unlink failed without success.

What solved my issue: right click on the folder containing the files > properties > Security tab. My user was missing in the list of "Group or user names". Adding it solved the issue.

My issue was not triggered by a pull but a checkout to another branch.

Hope it helps!