# How to fix "Deletion of directory '.git/objects/01' failed" in git gc

Tags: git, garbage-collection

I am running the command `git gc` on a git repository and am getting the error `Deletion of directory '.git/objects/01' failed.`

I am running the command in Git Bash on Windows 10.

I am pretty sure it isn't another process using the folder as I able to remove the directory within the same Git Bash shell via the `rm -r` command. Upon rerunning `git gc` I am informed `Deletion of directory '.git/objects/02' failed.`

Any ideas?

Comment: Is your current user the owner of all the files in the `.git` folder? You can check it with `ls -l .git`. You can find your username e.g. with `whoami`, `echo $USER` or `id -u -n`. You can change the owner e.g. with `sudo chown -R "$whoami" .git`, check https://askubuntu.com/a/49187/757721

Comment: Thanks for the comment @MichaelH. I checked and I do own the files. Note that I am able to delete the folder by using `rm -r` within the same shell.

Comment: Same here, I'm the owner. Why is it failing?

Answer (score 0):

I have got the same issue in Windows 10 using git version 2.25.1.windows.1
Actually it is a test repository.

In my case all the directories with issues are empty and git asks for permission 3 times for each directory.

I solved this with:

```
set GIT_ASK_YESNO=false
git gc
```

As suggested at [Unlink of file Failed. Should I try again?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389833/unlink-of-file-failed-should-i-try-again/28643598)  by andhdo.
This solve the messages but leaves empty folders in disk.