# Untracked files prevent checkout

Tags: git, intellij-idea

In my project under IntelliJ I checkout branch with old version in order to seee how something was done there. I didn't change antyhing and now when I want to return to master I receive this message:
Untracked files prevent checkout. Firstly there were only new webdriver file shown which was added to project in later version but now after executing command `git status` it shows all the class which were added in later version.
What happend ?
How can I skip it and return to master without breaking my project ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have any changes that you want to keep for the old branch, you can force checkout to master.

`git checkout -f BRANCH-NAME`

Edit: I do not use IntelliJ so I can't advise for that. Open a terminal, navigate to your git project and run the above command.

Comment: After executing command I receive this:Unlink of file 'src/test/resources/drivers/chromedriver110.exe' failed. Should I try again? (y/n)

Comment: check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389833/unlink-of-file-failed-should-i-try-again