# git gc command asks repeatedly Unlink of file '.git/objects/pack/pack-.pack' failed. Should I try again? , why ? and how to skip input Y/N

Tags: git

I am running

```
git gc --prune=now
```

and getting the result

```
Counting objects: 100% (619263/619263), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (132698/132698), done.
Writing objects: 100% (619263/619263), done.
Total 619263 (delta 316177), reused 608671 (delta 305796)
Unlink of file '.git/objects/pack/pack-15e469b10c92d51ece59ad7c055fc1ac64ff3056.pack' failed. Should I try again? (y/n) y
Unlink of file '.git/objects/pack/pack-15e469b10c92d51ece59ad7c055fc1ac64ff3056.pack' failed. Should I try again? (y/n) n
Unlink of file '.git/objects/pack/pack-4b025e2c952e34cf7b721520909ab216f6223fb3.pack' failed. Should I try again? (y/n)
```

why is this ? and

how do I avoid to interact with the command which is asking me to input y/n?

Comment: check if these files is opened by other process. For example ide, version manmger tools, close them and retry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is on Windows, make sure to use the [latest Git For Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) since [`git gc` was recently optimize to avoid that error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63662344/6309).

If not, double-check there is [no current process which could keep a handle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31738180/6309) to those Git files (as I [illustrated here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10181965/6309)). For instance, try the same command right after a reboot.