# Execute git command from bash script interactively

Tags: git, bash, shell, cygwin

I have a bash script that I'm executing from cygwin terminal.

Part of the script executes git clone on each repository listed in a file:

```
git clone ssh://me@example.net:29418/$1
```

Sometimes the git command will stop and ask for user input e.g.  try again (y/n)? (because it cannot rename HEAD.lock) but executing it from the shell script it just ignores the git command and carries on.

How do I make the shell script wait and pass input from the shell back to the git command?

Or is there another way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds a lot like [Git rebase got 'unlink of file failed' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698369/git-rebase-got-unlink-of-file-failed-error).

Is GIT_ASK_YESNO not set or incorrect in the shell script? Sounds like you want that env
variable to exist (looks like it's value doesn't matter, so GIT_ASK_YESNO=1 should be
sufficient)