# A way to access Git without installing client software? (Web access available?)

Tags: git

If I am working on a project from a hotel computer, is there a way to access a git repository (gitorious) using a web based client? I have a portable c++ compiler for the coding part, but I need to download and commit files to git without the ability to install git software. A portable git client would also work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hosted Git Solution With Server-Side Hooks?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8828153/hosted-git-solution-with-server-side-hooks)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is installable and portable versions of Git in https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/releases

Comment: What does this answer mean? It's just a link.

Comment: This answer does not provide a web based client, instead it provides a link to msysgit. Msysgit is a collection of files, which give you git functionality, similar to that of linux. After installing msysgit, you can check out files via the command line, like "git clone git://example.com/git/filename" :)

Comment: msysgit is retired. It is superseded by [Git for Windows](https://git-scm.com/download/win).

Answer (score 11):

Updating the new link to download portable Git for Windows archive file -

https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/releases

========

Update: 2015-09

It seems like msysgit is now redundant. Please see this - 
[msysGit vs Git for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3672272/msysgit-vs-git-for-windows/30181774#30181774)

The portable git 2.x version is available here - https://git-scm.com/download/win

A download starts automatically. You may cancel that one. Instead , there is a link to the "thumbdrive version" on the page.

Alternatively - https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases

Answer (score 5):

The portable msysgit runs direct from the USB stick. There are a few 'need to know' aspects such as [portable-git-windows-setting-home-environment-variable](http://markashleybell.com/portable-git-windows-setting-home-environment-variable.html) and [stackoverflow/fix-msysgit-portable-home-location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3454774/fix-msysgit-portable-home-location) - a Google search will pick them up.