# Hosted Git Solution With Server-Side Hooks?

Tags: git, hosting

There is already a similar "Hosted Solution for Version Control — with pre-commit hooks?" question on SO.  However, the user who asked that question only needed *client-side* hooks, and I'm looking for a Git host that allows you to configure *server-side* hooks.

(The reason I'm looking for this is so that we can prevent developers from being able to "push -f" on specific branches.  Client-side hooks are of <strike>no</strike> minimal use for solving this problem.)

So, can anyone recommend a Git host that allows its users to set server-side hooks?

(Bonus points if said host also offers an integrated bug tracker.)

*** EDIT ***

This question has already been answered, and the bounty awarded ... but if there are any Git hosts out there that make it easier to prevent "push -f" (either by providing that level of permissioning themselves, or by providing access to publish pre-recieve hooks, which would then let me use already-written/standard pre-recieve scripts) I would LOVE to hear about them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the list of hooks available on github is here: https://github.com/{user}/{repository}/admin/hooks

they have a generic post-receive hook, but not a generic pre-receive

you can code up your own here: https://github.com/github/github-services

Comment: Awesome, that sounds perfect ... except on the page you linked, under "How the services work", it specifically says "A post-receive background job is submitted ...", so I'm not clear on how I can use that to implement a pre-receive hook.  Could you please clarify?

Comment: yes, only post-receive.  You could do a git revert of any commits by collaborators not on X list for y branches, and then send them a nasty-gram.

Comment: I see, thank you.  Still WAY more work than if we just hosted our own Git (thanks for nothing GitHub), but at least there's a way.

Comment: I did not see anything on github under the repo/admin/hooks except some web hooks and services. It is not at all clear that any of those can be used to filter/reject pushes. If they can do so, please do expand on your answer - it would be very helpful to my team.

Answer (score 4):

This is a very old post, however, I wanted to make people aware that Assembla now offers Server Side Hooks for Subversion and Git repositories.  These are not like Github's where you have to standup a service to run them.  They are fully fledged pre and post commit hooks for git, including the update hook.

Check it out on [Assembla](http://blog.assembla.com/assemblablog/tabid/12618/bid/98012/Server-Side-Hooks-on-a-SaaS-repository.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I thought GitHub allows server side hooks

Comment: When I asked GitHub support (about push -f restrictions specifically, not about server-side hooks in general) they told me "This is not possible on server side currently, but it is something we want to do."  ... so I took that to mean they didn't support them.  How exactly would you put a server-side hook up on GitHub, since you can't ssh in to their servers?

Comment: There are a few projects out there that do this. Exactly what they do to integrate with GitHub, I'm not sure but will look. Since -f is not allowed, could you not delete the branch and push it again?

Comment: The problem is that -f *is* allowed; we're trying to prevent it (on master at least).

Comment: Ok. I'll see what I can dig out.

Comment: Thanks; was only looking for GitHub alternatives because their support rep specifically told me they couldn't prevent push -f (and allowing everyone to "push -f origin master" is, obviously, bad practice).  But if it is possible, then no need for an alternative ...

Answer (score 0):

Just tell the developers not to do this, and add a client-side hook as a precaution if you're worried about accidents. If you  worry about developers breaking policy by shoving up to master anyway, surely you have bigger problems than this. And it's not like a push -f would be destructive in a distributed system such as Git; everyone will still have their local copies of the overwritten commits.

Comment: The issue is people doing it accidentally, not on purpose (I agree, that would be a bigger problem!).  However, different developers use different clients (some of them use multiple clients).  Since the whole point is to eliminate any chance of a forced push, having a solution that works ... except for maybe that one dev on one client that didn't get the hook installed ... sort of defeats the purpose.

Honestly though, I thought server-side hooks were a basic feature of Git; I'm kind of shocked that no Git host lets you have them.

Comment: Git hosts don't want to let you run arbitrary code on their machines (or invent sandboxing), I imagine. If you install Gitosis (or whatever the hot new thing is; I just use Github) on your own server, you can install whatever hooks you want.

Comment: This can be a bigger issue than you'd think if the developers are fresh to Git, not in-house, and only really know to use it through an IDE's exposed interface. _F. M. L._

Comment: Not a good answer. The developers are new to git and have done it just after being described to them. No they are not stupid. They are inexperienced in git and anxious not to make big mistakes like this.