# Apply Chunk/Revert Chunk not working on Qt Creator on Windows

Tags: git, qt-creator, patch

I have git installed, and from Tools->Git->Diff, I can select Apply Chunk or Revert Chunk

[image]

On Linux it works, but on Windows it gives me

```
Unable to launch 'patch': Process failed to start: No such file or directory
```

Where do I need to install this patch.exe, and where do I get it from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There actually was patch.exe that came with Git, but it was located at "C:\Program Files\git\bin", and that wasn't added to PATH. I think that was because I didn't select the right option in the Git install wizard.

Qt Creator allows you to specify where the patch command is in its settings (the "Patch command" in the screenshot below).

[image]

Comment: This option has moved in Qt Creator 4.2.1 (and possibly earlier) to **Environment** > **System** > **Patch command**.  The option can be searched for in future versions by using the Filter textbox in the top-left.  Also later versions of Git for Windows install *patch* under **C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin**.

Answer (score -1):

Have you installed Git on Windows?

I'd suggest you to read the "Using msysGit on Windows" section of [Qt Creator: Using Version Control Systems](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qtcreator/creator-version-control.html). I'd hope installing `msysGit` would provide the missing `patch.exe`. Maybe you still have to change any setting in Qt Creator for telling it where `patch.exe` is.

Comment: I have git installed. But it is not msysGit, I got it from http://git-scm.com/downloads

Comment: @satuon well, that's `msysGit`. See the [download URL](https://github.com/downloads/msysgit/git/Git-1.8.0-preview20121022.exe).

Comment: It seems msysGit is just for building git yourself, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/3672312/492336