# Compile Glew git code with MinGW on Windows

Tags: windows, git, mingw, msysgit, glew

When looking on glew project page there's a git repository with the latest code.

Cloning the repository I saw that I need to download the extensions. The Makefile has a target called *extensions* that do the job of downloading everything from the internet.

The problem is that this Makefile is default for Unix systems. When I tried to build glew on Windows, using *msysgit* and *mingw* I get the following error:

```
mingw32-make.exe extensions
mingw32-make -C auto
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory `glew/auto'

--------------------------------------------------------------------
Creating descriptors
--------------------------------------------------------------------
rm -rf extensions/gl
bin/update_ext.sh extensions/gl registry/gl blacklist
Integer overflow in hexadecimal number at bin/parse_spec.pl line 337.
Hexadecimal number > 0xffffffff non-portable at bin/parse_spec.pl line 337.
Integer overflow in hexadecimal number at bin/parse_spec.pl line 337.
Hexadecimal number > 0xffffffff non-portable at bin/parse_spec.pl line 337.
Integer overflow in hexadecimal number at bin/parse_spec.pl line 337.
Hexadecimal number > 0xffffffff non-portable at bin/parse_spec.pl line 337.
Integer overflow in hexadecimal number at bin/parse_spec.pl line 337.
Hexadecimal number > 0xffffffff non-portable at bin/parse_spec.pl line 337.
Integer overflow in hexadecimal number at bin/parse_spec.pl line 337.
Hexadecimal number > 0xffffffff non-portable at bin/parse_spec.pl line 337.
bin/filter_gl_ext.sh     extensions/gl
Can't do inplace edit on extensions/gl/GL_HP_occlusion_test: Permission denied.
Can't open extensions/gl/GL_HP_occlusion_test: No such file or directory.
Can't do inplace edit on extensions/gl/GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object: Permission d
enied.
Can't do inplace edit on extensions/gl/GL_ARB_vertex_shader: Permission denied.
Can't open extensions/gl/GL_ARB_vertex_shader: No such file or directory.
Can't open extensions/gl/GL_ARB_vertex_shader: No such file or directory.
Can't open extensions/gl/GL_ARB_vertex_shader: No such file or directory.
grep: extensions/gl/GL_ARB_vertex_shader: No such file or directory
mingw32-make[1]: *** [extensions/gl/.dummy] Error 2
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory `glew/auto'
mingw32-make: *** [extensions] Error 2
```

I know this comes from *perl*, but how to solve it in Windows using MinGW and msysgit? 
I first think about other environment setup like *cygwin* but I already have a setup that build a dozen of other projects using my current setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem probably comes from the fact that you use `make` from MinGW (your `mingw32-make`) but `perl` from MSYS (which ships with *Git for Windows*). So what you'd need is an MSYS `make`.

Let me point out a common misconception before I continue: *msysgit* is the name of development environment to create the *Git for Windows* installer (also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3672312/1127485)). So usually people who just want to use Git on Windows should download *Git for Windows*, not *msysgit*. *msysgit* ships with all sorts of development stuff that is usually not needed, like `gcc` and (tadaa) `make`. So in you case, you'd really need *msysgit*, and I'd recommend the net installer from [here](http://msysgit.googlecode.com/files/msysGit-netinstall-1.8.4-preview20130916.exe). After the installation you should be able to launch `C:\msysgit\msys.bat`, change to your *glew* directory, and run `make extensions`.

Comment: I'll give it a try. Very good explanation about msysgit. If it works I'll mark as the anwser.