# Does git on Windows use MYSYS

Tags: windows, git

I noticed that the lastest version of git has a windows version.
Does this version still use MSYS/Cygwin, or has a more native port been created?
That is to say, does the current windows version of git, still have numerous shell scripts that it depends upon, or has the code been all ported to native executables.

Thanks

Comment: Will it change anything?

Comment: @zneak Latest version of Git - this changes everything. Again.

Comment: @bzlm I meant to ask if it will change anything that git uses MSYS/Cygwin or native functions.

Comment: @zneak Who cares? The question will be closed in a few minutes. :)

Comment: Hopefully the question now makes more sense.  I think maybe it belongs on a different site, but closing as generic "off-topic" I don't agree with.  Git is a software tool used by programmers, surely questions about it have a place either here or on superuser...

Comment: What isn't native about mingw-compiled binaries?  How would output from another compiler be "more native?"

Comment: I don't know whats non-native about minigw. But I was referring to the fact that git used to have a number of shell scripts that it depended upon. This required an abstraction layer when run on windows, which is what Cygwin/MSYS provided. There was talk of moving more things to C code, and I was wondering if the latest version was finally able to work on windows without an abstraction layer, so I'm reverting the question.

Comment: Note to "moderators": this question was 100% on topic for SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [msysGit-fullinstall-1.7.3.1-preview20101002.exe](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/list) full installer will install everything you need to compile Git on Windows.
That will allow you to see what exact libraries it needs.
As the [wiki page on "Working on Git" shows](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/MSysGit%3aWorkingOnMsysGit), it is still based on mingw:

> '`mingw`' is the repository Hannes Sixt set up starting with Dscho's rudimentary (and only half-working, but self-hosting nevertheless) MinGW port.
>   '`4msysgit`' (the default remote) is our fork of mingw, which basically has fixes we needed for msysGit.

Comment: what is the difference between Git-1.7.3.1-preview20101002.exe and msysGit-fullinstall-1.7.3.1-preview20101002.exe?

Comment: @Varun: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144082/different-between-msysgit-and-cygwin-git/3144417#3144417