# msysgit's scp unable to copy big files

Tags: windows, git, msysgit, scp, tail

I'm having trouble both tailing and scp-ing big files with msysgit (version 1.7.1.msysgit.0). [This post](http://lists-archives.org/mingw-users/05641-problems-with-large-file-s.html) indicates there is something wrong with underlying cygwin libraries.

Anybody know a good way to fix or circumvent these issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there are problems with big files due to lack of 64-bit support. Got a reply from an msysgit developer that 64-bit msys is required, and that I (or probably someone in greater need) will have to port it to 64-bit and report back to the msysgit team when done.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with a more recent version of msysgit?

[Issue 409](http://groups.google.com/group/msysgit/browse_thread/thread/8e14b51a59137946/6eb536506e12f5b5?lnk=gst&q=%22large+files%22#6eb536506e12f5b5)  and [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/msysgit/browse_thread/thread/fdea75f31733d8a7/ec9a3b66b0154cc0?lnk=gst&q=%22large+files%22#ec9a3b66b0154cc0) both reports fixes for large files checkouts (which isn't exactly your case, but could have some influence on your issue).

Comment: No I haven't (will tomorrow), but pretty sure it won't affect anything, since the problem also relates to tail (which of course only reads).

Comment: @Jonas: but a more recent version of msysgit means a more recent version of MSys, which could influence also the read issue. ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144082/different-between-msysgit-and-cygwin-git/3144417#3144417 )