# Cygwin causing a longjmp when running Git push

Tags: windows, git, command-line, cygwin

I am trying to run git from the command line on my Windows 7, 64 bit machine. It works fine for the most part. I tried pushing my local changes up to my private repository in the cloud.

The command I am trying to run is `git push origin master`

I use Cygwin 6.1 and it is causing the following error. Presumably related to the fact that I am running on a 64 bit machine

```
0 [main] git-remote-http 6168 fork: child -1 - died waiting for longjmp before initialization, retry 10, exit code 0xC0000135, errno 11 error: cannot fork() for send-pack: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

I followed the suggestions [here](http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2011-03/msg00604.html) to update my rebaseall file and reran the rebase command. But it didn't really seem to have helped.

Can anyone else reproduce the problem or have found a solution?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: At least you can try the same command with a msysgit installation instead of a Git under Cygwin. http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/

Comment: Yup. that worked for me. If you can put that as an answer, I would be glad to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other alternative is to use the [msysgit distribution](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/), which will allows you to make any git command without depending on the cygwin environment.

See also "[Difference between msysgit and 'cygwin + git'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144082/different-between-msysgit-and-cygwin-git/3144417#3144417)".

Answer (score 2):

The Cygwin mantra I used is "fork failures are rebase issues".  longjmp is not the issue, fork is.  Rebase is the only solution unfortunately.  In the past I have used custom scripts to build the rebase list.  I do this because you may be missing some DLLs, especially if you have hand-built stuff.  You can build a list with find and then pass it in to rebaseall with -T.  You should also consider trying a different base address other than the default one in rebaseall, look at the -b option.  64-bit machines seem to require larger spacing than 32-bit ones and so the default didn't work well for me.

Also if you change any DLLs on your system at all, you'll need to rebase again.

Note: Even after all this fork can still fail in Cygwin.  Virus scanners inject their DLLs which screw things up and Windows address space randomization doesn't help either.

Comment: It is worth pointing out that **rebaseall is a _cygwin_ notion**, nothing to do with _git_

Comment: Even better would be links to what the heck rebaseall is?

Answer (score 2):

The answer mfisch gave worked wonders for my problem.

A quick google search yielded [this result](http://cygwin.wikia.com/wiki/Rebaseall) which let me git push again in no time at all. The required packages came with the default cygwin install, so I didn't even have to install anything.