# Cygwin or Git Bash command window?

Tags: git, cygwin, git-bash

I'm new to Git. I downloaded Git and installed on my Windows. I saw Git provides a Git Bash command window. I also have Cygwin installed on my machine. Both Git Bash and Cygwin provide Git command line utilities. So my question is: Which one is the preferred way to use Git command: Running Git commands in Git Bash or Cygwin?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**[`git-bash`](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/blob/master/share/WinGit/Git%20Bash.vbs)** is enough, unless you need more recent bash feature (since the bash from MingW used by msysgit is quite old)

See also "[Difference between msysgit and Cygwin + git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144082/difference-between-msysgit-and-cygwin-git/3144417#3144417)".

For instance, [GitHub for Windows](http://windows.github.com/) would use msysgit, not git in Cygwin.

Comment: Github for windows uses "Git for Window". You mentioned this in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3144417/2455888). While this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16757442/2455888) states that Github for windows uses "PoshGit"

Comment: @haccks PoshGit, as illustrated by this pull request (https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git/pull/66) uses in turn msysgit.