# What is the difference between Git Bash and the GitHub for Windows shell?

Tags: git, bash, github

I'm referring to the shell that comes with GitHub for Windows (Github CLI), and Git Bash (which has a stand alone installer).

Comment: I think they're just two different kinds of consoles, but wait for someone who knows better than I.

Comment: have you seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14551989/cygwin-or-git-bash-command-window

Comment: I've tried using Git for Windows, but was first introduced to Git Bash during a Udacity course. Since I don't really work with Powershell, and a lot of data analysis is also done on Linux, which I do have some experience with, I prefer using Git Bash.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

Well, for one thing, the default shell that comes with GitHub for Windows is [PoshGit](https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git), which is a [Windows Power Shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell) environment for Git.  On the other hand, [Git Bash/msysGit](http://msysgit.github.io/) uses the [Bash shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)) (Bourne Again Shell) and [MinGW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mingw), which is a port of a Linux style environment and command line tools.

PoshGit will let you use Windows and Power Shell commands with Git at the command line, while Git Bash will let you use MinGW/Linux tools with Git at the command line.

Comment: Thank you, I was so confused at first too but now it makes sense!