# How to clone a Subversion repository with "GitHub for Windows"?

Tags: git-svn, github-for-windows

**Question**

I have [GitHub for Windows](http://windows.github.com/) installed and was wondering whether I can clone a Subversion repository with the "Git Shell" that comes along with "GitHub for Windows".

**Trial and error**

I tried the following:

1. Windows > Start > All Programs > GitHub, Inc > Git Shell
2. From the Git Shell PowerShell window: `git-svn clone -s http://example.com/my_subversion_repo .`

Then, I got the this error message:

```
The term 'git-svn' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the
name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and
try again. At line:1 char:8
+ git-svn <<<<  clone -s  http://example.com/my_subversion_repo .
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (git-svn:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

**Google**

Yes, I already googled, but didn't find an answer.

- git-svn: [Effectively Using Git With Subversion](http://viget.com/extend/effectively-using-git-with-subversion)
- [GitHub for Windows help](http://windows.github.com/help.html)
- ["github windows" subversion checkout](https://www.google.ch/search?q=%22github%20windows%22%20subversion%20checkout)
- [how to clone a subversion repository with "github for windows"](https://www.google.ch/search?q=how%20to%20clone%20a%20subversion%20repository%20with%20%22github%20for%20windows%22)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in "[What is the difference between Git Bash and the GitHub for Windows shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16757442/6309)", the GitHub Shell is based on [**`posh-git`**](https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git), which supports `git-svn`.

However, this [release note](http://lostechies.com/keithdahlby/2010/08/28/posh-git-release-v0-2/) mentions:

- `git-svn` operations: `git svn <tab>`

That means, no '`-`' between `git` and `svn`.

If the issue persists, and since [GitHub for Windows](http://windows.github.com/) also includes a [msysgit](https://code.google.com/p/msysgit/) distribution, you could open the msysgit bash instead, and try `git svn` commands there too.

---

Plus:

- "[Did GitHub shut down its support for Subversion clients?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53129732/6309)"
- "[Jan. 2024: Sunsetting Subversion support](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75206639/6309)"

Comment: Darn! No hyphen. Thank you!