# Did GitHub shut down its support for Subversion clients?

Tags: github, svn, tortoisesvn

GitHub [documents](https://help.github.com/articles/support-for-subversion-clients/) to support Subversion clients and I'm using that for many projects to include them in one of my working copies using `svn:externals`. Since yesterday I get the following error for all of those projects:

> The server at '[...]' does not support the HTTP/DAV protocol.

This happens to a long list of projects, some examples:

```
https://github.com/apache/commons-lang.git/tags/LANG_3_6
https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc.git/tags/REL42.2.2
https://github.com/ams-tschoening/kaitai_struct_tests.git/branches/libs_java_3rd_usage
```

I've already written to the support but didn't get any response yet. Maybe someone here knows already if this is a temporary issue only or permanent? Maybe this problem doesn't happen for other users at all for some reason?

Thanks!

Comment: Others have the same problem: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/tortoisesvn/qaJQ_K9Wbb8

Comment: There was an intentional change by the SVN-devs to implement more strict error checking on protocol level leading to the problem and they say it won't change on their site: https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/subversion-users/201811.mbox/<ba7c96e5-8a04-e676-9ee7-02357aeb3118%40apache.org>

Comment: IMHO, GitHub's "support for SVN clients" was never working as it should be. Yes, it worked for simple checkout, export and commit operations but that is not what "support" means. Anything more complex resulted in awkward errors.

Comment: @bahrep They supported everything I and many others seem to only need, including `svn:externals`, which in my opinion is somewhat complex already.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Does not work here anymore with ALL github repositories!
Using latest TortoiseSVN 1.11.0.

I've tried with version 1.10 of TortoiseSVN which still works, so this looks like a problem with TortoiseSVN 1.11 (which is linked against SVN 1.11).

Comment: Because of the wording of the error messages I simply didn't thought of client side problems, but TortoiseSVN really is the problem. I recently upgraded to 1.11.0 as well and switching back to 1.10 resolves the problems. Therefore I accept this answer, as it is the correct one in the concrete context of my problem. Next step will be to further debug why this occurs.

Answer (score 4):

This particular problem has been resolved on GitHub's side (as of 19 Dec 2018), please, see the **Outdated** section below.

However, you can get the error `The server at '[...]' does not support the HTTP/DAV protocol.` in other cases such as

- You navigate to SVN web interface URL instead of repository URL. Read the article [KB102: Subversion client errors caused by inappropriate repository URL](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00102/).
- You can receive this simply when you navigate to a URL that does not belong to a Subversion repository. Here is an example where we run `svn info` against `https://stackoverflow.com/`:

> svn info https://stackoverflow.com/ svn: E170013: Unable to connect to
>   a repository at URL 'https://stackoverflow.com' svn: E175003: The
>   server at 'https://stackoverflow.com' does not support the HTTP/DAV
>   protocol

---

**Outdated:**

Use Subversion 1.10 clients as a workaround.

Because of some changes in the latest Subversion 1.11.0 release, the newest SVN 1.11 clients do not work with GitHub's SVN bridge anymore and produce an error. Let's hope for a bugfix on SVN or GitHub's side soon.

You can find more information in this users@ Apache Subversion mailing list thread:  https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/90c028421ac86f787c2101ab61a70ec5fa0a6f4d617a8b87be802e5c@%3Cusers.subversion.apache.org%3E

Answer (score 2):

Warning: starting Jan. 2024, GitHub will do more than shutdown its support to SVN clients.

> ### [Subversion brownouts](https://github.blog/changelog/2023-11-06-subversion-brownouts/) (Nov. 2023)
>
> As announced earlier this year, GitHub is [removing support for the Subversion protocol](https://github.blog/2023-01-20-sunsetting-subversion-support/).
> Before permanent removal, we're running two brownouts where we will temporarily disable Subversion support.
>
> Those brownouts are scheduled for:
>
> - An 8 hour period on November 13, 2023, from 14:00 – 22:00 UTC / 7:00am – 3:00pm Pacific
> - A 24 hour period beginning December 5, 2023 at 10:00 UTC / 2:00am Pacific and ending at the same time on December 6
>
> As a reminder, Subversion support will be permanently removed on January 8, 2024.

---

> ### [Sunsetting Subversion support](https://github.blog/2023-01-20-sunsetting-subversion-support/) (**[Mat Copper](https://github.com/vtbassmatt)**, Jan 2023)
>
> Hello from Git Systems, the team that works on the Subversion subsystem at GitHub.
>
> As of January 8, 2024 (about a year from now), we will sunset Subversion support completely on GitHub.com.
> A release of GitHub Enterprise Server sometime in early 2024 will also remove Subversion support. Read on for more details.
>
> In 2010, [when GitHub introduced Subversion support](https://github.blog/2010-04-01-announcing-svn-support/), the version control landscape was very different. Many customers were using centralized version control systems.
> Subversion was already 10 years old and in good company with other centralized systems, while Git was still a relative newcomer. At that point in time, it was not yet clear that distributed version control would eventually take over, and even less clear that Git would be the dominant system.
> By natively supporting Subversion on top of a Git backend, GitHub made it easier for customers to move to Git while changing their workflows over in a gradual way.
>
> Fast forward to now, and wow, have things changed. [Git enjoys up to 94% usage by developers](https://survey.stackoverflow.co/2022/#section-version-control-version-control-systems), and Subversion is a lot rarer in the wild than it used to be.
> Our traffic numbers inside GitHub back this up: fewer than 0.02% of requests made to the Git backend come through a Subversion endpoint, and only about 5,000 repositories see even a single Subversion request each month.
> It’s clear that Subversion support is no longer helping people migrate to Git.
>
> But hey, if the Subversion system just works and doesn’t bother anyone, there’s no reason to make any changes, right?
> The reality is that there’s an ongoing maintenance cost to any software, and that goes extra for public-facing services on the internet. As the use of GitHub has evolved and the number of Subversion requests has declined dramatically, we plan to focus our efforts entirely on Git.
>
> Why do people still use Subversion on GitHub, anyhow?
> Besides simple inertia, there were workflows which Git didn’t support until recently.
> The main thing we heard when speaking with customers and communities was checking out a subset of the repository–a single directory, or only the latest commit.
> I have good news: with [sparse checkout](https://github.blog/2020-01-17-bring-your-monorepo-down-to-size-with-sparse-checkout/), [sparse index](https://github.blog/2021-11-10-make-your-monorepo-feel-small-with-gits-sparse-index/), and [partial clone](https://github.blog/2020-12-21-get-up-to-speed-with-partial-clone-and-shallow-clone/), Git can now do a pretty decent job at these workflows.
>
> We will maintain Subversion support until January 8, 2024 on GitHub.com.
>
> After that date, it will be turned off and removed.
> Late in 2023, we’ll run a few hours-long and then day-long brownouts to help flush out any remaining use of the feature.
> The next version of GitHub Enterprise Server to ship after January 8, 2024, will also remove Subversion support.

Comment: Is this still on schedule?

Comment: @marcolopes Yes. [Yes, it is](https://github.blog/changelog/2023-11-06-subversion-brownouts/)

Answer (score 1):

No, it is just a bug on GitHub side.

Check out the below... (I found this messages from the link uploaded by bahrep)

The root cause is that GitHub does not implement Subversion's HTTP/DAV
protocol correctly.

In 1.11, the Subversion client has become stricter about the server
requirements (see: https://svn.apache.org/r1825302). Specifically, we
require that the server sends DAV response headers to the OPTIONS
request, which we use for capability negotiation. Here's an example of a
correct response:

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 04 Nov 2018 15:40:24 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
DAV: 1,2
DAV: version-control,checkout,working-resource
DAV: merge,baseline,activity,version-controlled-collection
DAV: http://subversion.tigris.org/xmlns/dav/svn/depth
...

The GitHub server does not return any DAV: header for the OPTIONS
request, so the response is considered incorrect. I suggest sending a
bug report to GitHub; the attached script can be used to simulate
Subversion's OPTIONS request.

In the meantime, staying with 1.10.x appears to be the only option if
you have to use GitHub's SVN protocol.