# How to run ./script.sh in windows Git shell?

Tags: windows, git, bash, shell

Maybe it's awkward, but I can't run .sh file on Windows when working in Git shell. Probably I have to install something, but I thought that Git will support that bash command (I know Windows don't use sh files).

I am doing installation steps from [GameClosure](http://docs.gameclosure.com/guide/install.html) and after `$ ./install.sh` a window with application selection to open sh file appears (like that when you try to open unknown file in Windows, it asks what application to open this you would like to use).
I've tried open it with Git shell, but failed... **What I have to do to run this file** and proceed with installation steps from GameClosure tutorial?**

Here is a screenshot (alert in polish, but I think you all know this message).
[image: Screenshot (Polish)]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using the `git-bash` available with [msysgit](https://code.google.com/p/msysgit/), with the [`Git Bash.vbs`](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/blob/master/share/WinGit/Git%20Bash.vbs) shortcut.

[Msysgit is also packaged](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11928561/6309) within [GitHub for Windows](http://windows.github.com/), even though the [shell exposed is a Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16757393/what-is-the-difference-between-git-bash-and-the-github-for-windows-shell/16757442#16757442) one based on [posh-git](https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git). That (powershell) would explain why `*.sh` scripts cannot run on it.

The [OP Szorstki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1030134/szorstki) mentions [in the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16772202/how-to-run-script-sh-in-windows-git-shell/16772497#comment24165618_16772497) that there actually is a setting in the GitHub for Windows app, that can set up Git Bash as the default command line tool.

Comment: Ok, thanks - there is configuration in GitHub windows app, that can set up Git Bash as the default command line tool.

Comment: @Szorstki no, as I have linked in the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11928561/where-is-git-exe-located : msysgit is packaged within GitHub for Windows. You can then launch the Git Bash script which will run a msys Unix-type compatible shell (as explained in the [msysgit FAQ](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions)).

Answer (score 1):

Try installing [bash for Windows](http://win-bash.sourceforge.net/) and running the script ag again after executing bash from cmd.exe.

Answer (score 0):

*Invokes the right shell, no unnecessary windows and invokes a bash script afterwards which will be hold.*

- **Create a Shortcut** to `mintty.exe` on your desktop, for example
- **Edit properties** of the shortcut and change the target (keep the path):
- `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\mintty.exe" -h always /bin/bash -l -e 'D:\folder\script.sh'`