# create a sub-repository and insert it in the main project

Tags: git, github, repository

I'm very new to git, I use it through gitHub, and I wanted to know if there's a way to create a sub-repository that is then included in the main one.
For example, if I have a library with modules, I'd like some of them to be in a repository on their own, with issues and all the features offered by git, but at the same time I want them to be included in the library repo.
How can I do this?

Comment: Is [submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) maybe the feature you're looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for [git submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules).

Basically, each of the libraries you mention will be added as a submmodule. Each such submodule will have a repository of its own, and the master repository will reference this via the entry in the `.gitmodules` file.

As @Chris mentions in comments below, you may want to [explore git subtrees](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/05/alternatives-to-git-submodule-git-subtree/) as well.

Comment: Submodules are indeed a good option here. Many users prefer [subtrees](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/05/alternatives-to-git-submodule-git-subtree/), and they're worth a look too.

Comment: Is there a way to configure it via gitHub or should I download the git shell?

Comment: @Phate01 You can use the [`git-bash`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16757393/1860929), which comes in pre-installed with git for windows. I'm not really sure on configuring this using `github` tool.