# Git Hook under Windows

Tags: windows, git, post, hook

I have the following code to checkout in a working directory in the hook post-receive:

```
#!/bin/sh
git --work-tree=d:/websites/__gitweb --git-dir=d:/_gitrepo.git/ checkout -f
```

Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work. However, the command does work when I enter just this in the windows command line (cms):

```
git --work-tree=d:/websites/__gitweb --git-dir=d:/_gitrepo.git/ checkout -f
```

I have checked the permissions and the executing attributes but nothing.

**UPDATE:**

I think I'm getting closer. Now I know what the problem is but I don't know why is this happening. The hook is actually being triggered but I receive this message:

```
remote: Starting copy from repository to work tree...
remote: fatal: Not a git repository: 'd:/_gitrepo.git/'
remote: Finished.
```

I have tried to change the path of d: to the whole network path but it still doesn't work. If I go to the remote repository and I do a git log, the changes are there and if I run the hook with sh, it works.
Why is it saying that it is not a git repository when clearly it is?

Comment: Have tried removing the `#!/bin/sh` top line? Windows do not support it.

Comment: Hi Jimmy, thanks for your reply. I tried that and it still doesn't work.

Comment: what's the output of this command in your case? If you're on windows, you may use paths like `/d/websites/__gitweb` while using msysgit

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I finally got it working!
This is really weird. I had to type a `pwd` to see where actually is the batch being located and it showed the hook location on the server. However, in the next line I added a `hostname` and it showed me my local hostname.
Then I add the whole path just like:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Starting copy from repository to work tree..."
pwd
hostname
git --work-tree=//remotehost/d$/Webseiten/__gitweb --git-dir=//remotehost/d$/_gitr
epo.git checkout -f
echo "Finished."
```

I hope this solution works for someone

Comment: I had the same problem - then realized because my remote repo was added with a file system path (\\server\path) the hooks on the remote didn't execute on the remote machine. Looking into http://bonobogitserver.com/ to set up remote git server.

Answer (score 4):

For a shell script (and those hook scripts will be executed as shell, even in Windows, through the [msys layer of msysgit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3144417/6309)), you could use a different sort of path:

```
#!/bin/sh
git --work-tree=/d/websites/__gitweb --git-dir=/d/_gitrepo.git/ checkout -f
```

See also other possibilities with "[Posix path conversion in MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Posix_path_conversion)"

Comment: Hi! I tried that already and if I type in the Git Bash `sh post-receive` and it works. But the problem is that the script doesn't seem to trigger.