# How to run a script or command after every Git operation? (in Windows)

Tags: git

I need to run a script, say writing to a log file, after every git operation (checkout, pull, push, merge, etc.). Something like this:

```
> git checkout
> writelog.bat
```

But I don't want to manually run writelog.bat each time the git command completes.

I know about hooks, but not sure how to use it here.

Is there a way to do it in Git?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run git hook script on windows, using repository through filesystem?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23384196/how-to-run-git-hook-script-on-windows-using-repository-through-filesystem)