# Windows environment Git hook pre-commit not executing

Tags: windows, git, bash

Windows 7.
Bash shell.

I've made a file called *pre-commit* with the following content but nothing happens.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "PRE-COMMIT EXECUTE"
mvn compile
exit 1
```

First: I have seen references to .git/hooks and C:/GitInstalledDir/hooks for the file location so where exactly is this file suppose to go?

Second: If it's to go in ".git" what directory is this, my user directory?

Comment: .git is a directory created inside your working tree.

Comment: You might find [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23384196/how-to-run-git-hook-script-on-windows-using-repository-through-filesystem) helpful.

Comment: Thank you both! Very helpful link you provided................"Every Git repository has a .git/hooks folder with a script for each hook you can bind to."