# How can I create new branch from zip file into at github repo

Tags: github

I have downloaded in Windows libray LIB and edited it to suit my needs ie adding some usefull functions that I would like to share with original libraty author.

How ever it seams that I must install some Cygwin in order to have github pull request working and I don't want that.

I want directly to upload my version to orginal repository via browser without needed to login into github and doing all that nasty cloning and such.

Ideally I would like to send with zip my verison of the lib that would create oo the fly new branch to orginal repo and make pull request to master.

Is this possible in github?

Answer (score 1):

> Ideally I would like to send with zip my version of the lib

This is not what Git (source control manager) and GitHub (Git repository hosting service) are for.

If you are modifying sources (from the zip archive), you should contribute back to the source repository of that library, through a GitHub fork of said sources.

Again, Git is about managing sources (mostly text files), not artifacts (like a zip of sources).
Artifacts are stored in artifact manager (like [Nexus](https://blog.sonatype.com/2009/04/what-is-a-repository/) or [Artifactory](https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/what-is-a-software-artifact/))

If you want to push back to GitHub, you would be pushing back text files, not a aip archive.

---

> How ever it seams that I must install some Cygwin in order to have github pull request working

No: a pull request is entirely done on the server side, through the web GUI, on *your* fork.

> I want directly to upload my version to original repository via browser without needed to login into github and doing all that nasty cloning and such.

You only can push back to your fork, not to the original repo. See "[Git fork is git clone?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6286877/6309)"
Once pushed, you can then create a [pull request](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-pull-request).

So if you haven't already done so:

- fork the original repo (done through the web GUI)
- clone that repo with Git ([you can use msysgit](http://msysgit.github.io/), [no need for Cygwin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3144417/6309))
- `git checkout -b aNewBranch` (this doesn't change any file, it just creates a new branch to isolate your changes)
- report your changes in it, git add and git commit
- `git push origin aNewBranch`

Then, on the web interface on your fork, select that '`aNewBranch`' and create a pull request from there.

See also those "[couple of tips for Pull Requests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14681796/6309)".

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with a zip file

Comment: @clairestreb Yes, because a zip file is not the proper way to send back contribution to GitHub.

Comment: then you should explain that, because your answer does not directly address the question

Comment: @clairestreb I agree. I have completed the answer to address zip first.