# What's the equivalent of sudo in msys?

Tags: windows, bash, command-line, msysgit, msys

I'm writing a cross-platform shell script that's supposed to work on Unix, Cygwin, and msys. In my shell script I need to perform actions with elevated privileges. On Unix you would do this via `sudo`, and on [Cygwin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4090301/root-user-sudo-equivalent-in-cygwin) via something like `cygstart --action=runas`. What's the equivalent for msys?

All my Googling so far has only turned up [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22767885/msysgit-sudo-like-command), which isn't practical from a shell script since you have to interact with the GUI.

Comment: What is the script you are trying to run? Keep in my mind. Its not a unix shell, it just emulates one. You probably would need to start msysgit with an elevated privilege.

Comment: @deostroll The commands I am trying to run are: `mkdir -p`, `tee`, and `chmod` ([source code for script](https://github.com/jamesqo/sinister/blob/master/sinister#L116-L119)).

Comment: This is not a shell problem. Not only is `sudo` an external command, it is not even defined by [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696699/utilities/contents.html), and is certainly not available by default on many Unix or Unix-like systems, including many Linux distros (e.g. Arch).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I may have found a solution using PowerShell:

```
escape()
{
    RESULT="$1"
    RESULT="${RESULT/\'/\\\'\'}" # replace ' with \''
    RESULT="${RESULT/\"/\\\\\\\"}" # replace " with \\\"
    echo "''$RESULT''" # PowerShell uses '' to escape '
}

sudo()
{
    ESCAPED=()
    for ARG in "$@"
    do
        ESCAPED+=($(escape "$ARG"))
    done

    SHELL_PATH=$(cygpath -w $SHELL)
    PS_COMMAND="[Console]::In.ReadToEnd() | Start-Process '$SHELL_PATH' '-c -- \"${ESCAPED[*]}\"' -Verb RunAs"
    cat /dev/stdin | powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass "$PS_COMMAND"
}
```

<s>Definitely a bit</s> Extremely hackish, but it's better than nothing. (Or Batch files, for that matter.)

Answer (score 2):

[Elevate](http://code.kliu.org/misc/elevate/) does a decent job at this, though it's not entirely `sudo`-equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

From https://www.msys2.org/wiki/Sudo/, if you didn't make your MSYS2 root readonly for users, and don't want to do any Windows administrative tasks from MSYS2, you don't need `sudo`. But If you do need sudo the suggestion from the MSYS2 maintainers is to use a replacement (MSYS2 doesn't support all the things GNU/Linux `sudo` needs). Their suggestion of a replacement that doesn't have "*horrible security flaws*" is [win-sudo](https://github.com/imachug/win-sudo). It doesn't support all the arguments of `sudo` on GNU/Linux systems, but it does work for the simplest case of doing `sudo foo` to run `foo` with elevated privileges.