# Git clone itself doesn't change version

Tags: git

I just clone git to itself still the version of my git is still the same?
Running `git --version` still displays the old version. I cloned for too long, and I can git is till the same?

Note: my environment is Windows.

Comment: post more details,
try to find out `git` location using `which git`

Comment: using `which git` displays `/bin/git`

Comment: did you you compiled `git` using `make && make install`?
this step will create `git` binary you need to create a link to this `git` to replace `/bin/git`

Comment: `git` is not upgraded by `git clone`. It's like saying "I ordered a red pen but my diary is still all blue"... Tag the question with your operating system, the exact mechanism of upgrading the installed `git` will depend on that.

Comment: i cloned git using `git clone https://github.com/git/git` as it was mentioned here http://git-scm.com/downloads

Comment: I got downvoted because I just forgot to put the environment? :( harsh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

git clone https://github.com/git/git would only clone git source.
You still need to compile and install it in order to see any change.
You can see the process describe in the [`INSTALL` file](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/INSTALL).
Those are Unix sources.

---

If you want to upgrade on Windows, then you need [msysgit](http://msysgit.github.io/), which is the [Windows development environment for git](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3144417/6309), needed for building "Git for Windows").
See the ["contribute" section](http://msysgit.github.io/#contribute): you can install that building environment with [`msysGit-netinstall-1.9.4-preview20140929.exe`](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/releases/download/Git-1.9.4-preview20140929/msysGit-netinstall-1.9.4-preview20140929.exe).

The [msysgit mailing list](http://osdir.com/ml/msysgit/) can help too.

Comment: I see, how should I do that?

Comment: I am running on windows

Comment: so it's an .exe huh? :( then I just cloned git for too long for nothing? :(

Comment: @meetmahpuppy that exe will in turn clone a modified version of git/git, and setup a development environment with msys C compiler.