# How to fix GITHUB commit date?

Tags: git, date, github, commit

I am working on a github hosted project. For testing reasons, I have to move my computer date to somewhere in the future (2012) and forgot to bring it back to normal time when doing a git commit  / push.

The actual commit is now actually saved as 2012 instead of 2010 and it's screwing our github view since they always appear on top.

Is there any way to fix that?

Comment: it's your latest commit or not ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If not too many people have already pulled from that GitHub repo, you could locally change the  `GIT_AUTHOR_DATE` and `GIT_COMMITTER_DATE` of your old commit, and `git push --force` that to the GitHub repo.
(Just be prepared to point out people to the [RECOVERING FROM UPSTREAM REBASE](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#_recovering_from_upstream_rebase) section of the [`git rebase`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) man page)

See [How can one change the timestamp of an old commit in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454734/how-can-one-change-the-timestamp-of-an-old-commit-in-git) for the specifics on the `git filter-branch` command required for that kind of operation.