# avoid timestamps in git

Tags: git, github

How can you systematically set git up to set all timestamps to be at some arbitrary point e.g. 1970-01-01 or something?

Are timestamps ever used, or are they just trivia that it is safe to anonymize?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I really have no idea why one would want to do this, but for creating new commits with commit and author date set to that date and time, you can do:

```
export GIT_AUTHOR_DATE="1970-01-01T00:00:00"
export GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="1970-01-01T00:00:00"
```

To rewrite all the old dates in the repository you can easily modify the example here:

- [How can one change the timestamp of an old commit in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454734/how-can-one-change-the-timestamp-of-an-old-commit-in-git)

... to rewrite every commit with those dates.  Note that this will change the object name (SHA1sum) of every commit, of course.

As for whether the dates are "trivia" - they certainly aren't to me!  It's frequently useful to know when a commit was made, and not just its position in the commit graph.  Also, less seriously, [gource](http://code.google.com/p/gource/) needs those data for its beautiful animations of your repository history ;)