# Is there a "git touch" so I can push the same file with a new timestamp?

Tags: git, timestamp

I have an automated build tool that uses the modification date of the file in the output. Is there a way to "git touch" the file and save that to Git without having to actually modify the file?

Comment: `git` doesn't even track file time stamps, except for commit time stamps, so the answer to this is going to be no.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I think what you need is `touch` command if you are on `unix` operating system.

Git can however allow you to do a empty commit if you use `--allow-empty` option.

Eg. `$ git commit --allow-empty -m "Trigger notification"` would cause an empty commit which you can then push and do another deploy.

Answer (score 10):

This will update hash and timestamp of last commit, without any changing or message dialog.

```
git commit --amend --no-edit
```

Comment: This would rewrite the history and require a force push.

Comment: @DavidG sure. Of course, you should not try to change the hash of already pushed commits.

Comment: In order to change the timestamp (and hash) of the last commit, `git commit --amend --no-edit` didn't change the date of the last commit, but `git commit --amend --reset-author --no-edit` did.


For more information, in `man git commit`:

--reset-author

When used with -C/-c/--amend options, or when committing after a conflicting cherry-pick, declare that the authorship of the resulting commit now belongs to the committer. This also renews the author timestamp.

Comment: In order to change the timestamp of older commits, this was very useful:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454734/how-can-one-change-the-timestamp-of-an-old-commit-in-git/31540373#31540373

Answer (score 8):

Git works on content hashes so it won't see your change and I doubt it has that functionality. I'd recommend that you echo the current date into that file rather than relying on modified date.

As a sideonote, relying on modification date is going to cause you many more problems as local time can be different between machines.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I don't mind the local time issues since the only one that really matters is what the build machine sees, I am also only looking for the day things were modified.