# GIT: change commit date to author date

Tags: git, date, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

Is it possible to change the commit date from my commit to the author date?

I adapted some commits and now the dates are all the same. I want to set it back to the old dates (or the author dates). Is this possible?

I am using Sourcetree so I have the git command line but I am not a pro at that. My external repository is bitbucket.

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/454734/how-can-one-change-the-timestamp-of-an-old-commit-in-git ?

Comment: Yea but I actually pushed the new dates.

Comment: But the new commit dates reflect reality. Why do you want to hide the truth?

Comment: Because I am using gource to show the progress. and I just changed the author. So actually that is not a change to the code.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

Since git 1.6.3 `git rebase` has `--committer-date-is-author-date` for this purpose.

```
git rebase --committer-date-is-author-date
```

*Original answer:*
There's no easy way to set the *committer* dates (edit: but see "edit 2" below).  The *author* dates are easy to adjust (at commit time) since `--date` will let you specify each one as you go.

The environment variable `GIT_COMMITTER_DATE` can be used to force a different time stamp at the time you make the commit.  Note, however, that you'd need to adjust this for each commit you "replay".  The resulting new commit will have a different SHA-1 (because you've changed some bits in it, namely, the committer date field), which means you must redo all its descendent commits.

This is what `git filter-branch` does (re-create some, many, or all commits with changes made along the way, keeping a mapping from old SHA-1 IDs to new SHA-1 IDs and adjusting the parents of even-otherwise-untouched commit copies so that the "new" DAG of new SHA-1 IDs matches the "old" DAG in every possible way, i.e., in every way except for SHA-1 IDs and any other changes made by your filter(s)).

In other words, to do this, you must use `git filter-branch` to rewrite history, with all that this implies.  [Edit: you can literally do it without `git filter-branch`, e.g., by doing it in `git rebase -i` instead, but the effect is the same.]

**Edit 2**: as eis noted in a comment (since removed), `git rebase` has `--committer-date-is-author-date` for this purpose.  It still does the same history rewriting, but it's a lot more convenient than doing it with the raw `git filter-branch` command.

Comment: `--committer-date-is-author-date` seems to be quite broken when combined with `--root`, unfortunately.

Comment: Notice that we can use e.g., `git rebase --committer-date-is-author-date HEAD~3` to only apply it to the most three recent commits.

Comment: @HeYifei何一非 Yes—but only if those three commits are ordinary single-parent commits; watch out for merges in your history. The `HEAD~3` notation counts back three first-parents.

Comment: True, but I had put a `break` in the middle of a `rebase -i` and I couldn't do _another_ rebase with the existing rebase in progress. `filter-branch` was the only way in this unique scenario.

Answer (score 136):

## Short Answer:

```
git filter-branch --env-filter 'export GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="$GIT_AUTHOR_DATE"'
```

---

### Explanation:

`filter-branch` lets you rewrite your git history. It can apply transformations to each commit or filter out commits based on certain criteria. See `git filter-branch --help` for a comprehensive description and usage instructions.

`--env-filter` allows you to set the environment variables that are present during the creation of the new history. It is evaluated for each commit separately.

Comment: @S.TarıkÇetin this command simply sets `committer-date=author-date` as requested by kevingoos

Comment: We can also define commit range at the end `git filter-branch -f --env-filter '...' 338f1ac1..HEAD`.

Comment: To do it on the most recent commit (the head), use `HEAD^..HEAD` as the commit range. Also, for the options, adding `-f/--force` may sometimes be necessary (for example you still have a backup from last run).

Answer (score 8):

### One-liner with `filter-repo`:

You can also use [`filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo) (a recommended replacement for `filter-branch`) like this:

```bash
git filter-repo --commit-callback 'commit.committer_date = commit.author_date'
```

This is significantly more performant than `filter-branch`.

Comment: Be aware that some Git commands can get greatly confused and misbehave if the committer timestamps are not monotonically increasing. This can happen after this command if applied to a history where commits have been rearranged with `git rebase`.

Comment: @j6t Thanks for pointing that out; though it's not specific to my answer; this applies to the accepted answer as well.

Comment: copy all values from author to committer: `git filter-repo --commit-callback 'commit.committer_date = commit.author_date; commit.committer_name = commit.author_name; commit.committer_email = commit.author_email'`

Answer (score 5):

I wanted to piggyback on the [answer from jsphpl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38586928/1236018) because I was looking for a way to do this, but with two differences:

- I only wanted to change the commits in my current branch
- I wanted the rewritten commits to be signed

First you will need the ID of the first commit in your branch:

```bash
git log master..your-branch-name --pretty="%H" | tail -1
```

The output of that will look something like this: `c04b195ca1ed4c8a18c6a98d67b8a764a3006afc`

Take that ID and plug it into the command below:

```bash
git filter-branch -f \
--env-filter 'export GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="$GIT_AUTHOR_DATE"' \
--commit-filter 'git commit-tree -S "$@";' \
c04b195ca1ed4c8a18c6a98d67b8a764a3006afc^...your-branch-name
```

The commit date and author date of each commit should now match. You can double check by running the command below to easily view and compare the commit date values:

```bash
git log --format="%H %cI %aI %s" master...your-branch-name
```