# Preserve dates in Bitbucket while rebasing

Tags: git, timestamp, bitbucket

I widely use the `git rebase --interactive` technique, as this allows to keep the history lean and mean. For example, if I have a branch of 3 commits: `a->b->c`, and then I discover that the commit `a` has a misprint, I would prefer to modify the commit `a` directly instead of creating a commit `d` that fixes the issue. For sure the history changes (we have now a branch of `a'->b'->c'` commits), but the dates shown in *git bash* reflect the initial history of the commits. In other words, if the commit `a` is created yesterday, the commit `a'` also has this creation date as shown in `git log`.

But that is not true if the history is viewed from the *Bitbucket* commits history. Somehow Bitbucket ignores the dates that git bash uses, and shows the actual dates of modification (e.g. today).

So my first question is: which dates do *git bash* and *Bitbucket* use, and what is the difference? The follow up question is more practical: what is the best way to perform the interactive rebase that preserves the dates of commits as shown in *Bitbucket*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try for testing to do your rebase with the `--committer-date-is-author-date` option illustrated [here by torek](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28537098/6309).
You will need to do it as an aditional non-interactive rebase, once your interactive rebase is done, since that option is incompatible with `-i`.

But the idea is to check if BitBucket show the [committer date (last modification: today), vs. author date (commit creation date)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11857467/6309).
See by contrast how [GitHub uses those two dates](https://help.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-profile/troubleshooting-commits-on-your-timeline).

Comment: That helped me. Thank you!