# Remote commit dates not corresponding with local

Tags: git, github, git-commit, git-push, git-rebase

I recently rebased my most recent commits to my master branch interactively (`rebase -i`). I squashed multiple commits into just two, discarding unneeded commit messages (`fixup`), and subsequently pushed to remote master (on GitHub).

What I noticed is that the commit dates in the remote repo does not correspond to the date of the commit (as provided by `git log`). Rather the commit dates on the remote branch correspond to the date of rebasing and pushing. From what I can find, the commit history on the remote repo is supposed to correspond to the local one, but the commit dates in my remote and local branch are divergent. I can only assume this has something to do with rebasing, and that my original commits where tampered with.

###### Output from `git log`:

```
% git log
commit 09e76b90aa1c0c3f6a780c8b29b0c93dc2f57143 (HEAD -> master, origin/master)
Author: John Doe <john@doe.com>
Date:   Wed Apr 12 13:23:12 2023 +0200

    1st imputation success no interaction or random sl

commit 2ef860eabd90dfff5197c66a3dbb541174e1146b
Author: John Doe <john@doe.com>
Date:   Thu Mar 9 22:32:49 2023 +0800

    First commit on Arch Linux
```

###### History on GitHub:

[image]

- **Why do the commit dates on the local and remote branch diverge?**
- **Is there a way to change Git/GitHub's behaviour so that the commit dates correspond?**

Comment: It's talking about _commit_ dates, and the output from log shows _author_ date. If you showed the commit dates in log, you would see that there is a match. Try with `git log --pretty=fuller`

Comment: @eftshift0 The commit dates are indeed identical. I was unaware there was a difference between commit date and author date. [`git rebase --committer-date-is-author-date HEAD~2`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28537098/9434803) and then forrce-pushing to remote resolved the issue. Please add as an answer and I will tick it off as resolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's talking about commit dates, and the output from log shows author date. If you showed the commit dates in log, you would see that there is a match. Try with `git log --pretty=fuller`

---

With regards to the second question:

[In order to change the commit dates to correspond to author dates, git rebase has `--committer-date-is-author-date` for this purpose.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28537098/9434803) Rebase with the added flag and then force-pushing to remote resolved the issue for this particular case.

Code example:

```
git rebase --committer-date-is-author-date HEAD~2
git push -f origin master
```

Comment: Pål: Consider using `--force-with-lease` instead of `--force`, here (safer)