# github show the commit in the "wrong" order

Tags: git, github, timezone, rebase

We have two developer who works on 2 machines with a different timezone.

1. time 1:  A pushed commit 'commit 1' (hufan's commit in the next example, 5 hours ago from now)
2. time 2:  B pull the changes time
3. time 3:  B add the new 'commit 2'  (zhifan's commit, 15 minutes ago).
4. time 4:  B push the commit 2 to github.

   So commit 1 comes comes before commit 2 in fact.  However, the github shows commit 2 is ahead of commit 1.

[image: hufan's commit is 5 hours ago, but zhifan's commit is 15 minutes ago]

Questions:

1. why the hufan commit is shown as the latest commit in github?
2. current I'm on a feature branch,  if I run git rebase master, which commit will be applied first and why?  I can't try it now because I have too latest merge-base now.

hufan TZ:  Wed Dec 28 12:47:22 GMT+7 2016 (7 hours after the standard time)

zhifan TZ:  Wed Dec 28 20:52:10 SGT 2016 (8 hours ahead of the standard time)

git-log graph:

Since I did 2 merge with master between the 2 commits, so things may has become complex a lot.  when you check the git-log, you can search "Commit 1" "Commit 2" for my comments.

```
* 1ea4b40157d2e5281573f90d675ac9186e46072e Fan Zhihui Thu Dec 29 06:34:43 2016 +0800 a bug of code reorg, fixed it now
* 0e09ec8d0db8e4500d0127d07644478c8caedae7 Fan Zhihui Wed Dec 28 21:29:05 2016 +0800 made some changes for qa
* edf5e4290f232f7b83c086bd8b235c1082ba287c Fan Zhihui Wed Dec 28 21:08:32 2016 +0800 add key also for the cluster since sometime we have no password
* bc9a53fdaa77e082eeebe5808618197bc0a29b22 Fan Zhihui Wed Dec 28 20:24:38 2016 +0800 add username & password information into cluster ***** Commit 2 *****
* 230598bf1879b11f5e255d52f6f89f38a716f773 Fan Zhihui Wed Dec 28 20:18:55 2016 +0800 added task_logger to cluster/dbnode component
*   7418a1fa69f81122ab5723f75660d63d912c4941 Fan Zhihui Wed Dec 28 20:03:19 2016 +0800 Merge branch 'master' into dbaas   ** I merge master again since I forget to pull last time:(
|\
| * 8d6c34ce5381b20ba6aa0abb1cd04d0c23478cec yyyyyyyy Wed Dec 28 14:42:24 2016 +0800 enhance api of generate_sql_based_on_dict
| * da178bd520560db95a2d41e1a61e0cdec471e414 cccccc Wed Dec 28 06:22:11 2016 -0700 fix error of display name&paramter name
| * ef21151c27e49e495891252674f2bac5b34d645e cccccc Wed Dec 28 05:57:16 2016 -0700 work around the memory leak problem
| * 41debef87209b3118683b7fe7c38246f8b3389ca cccccc Wed Dec 28 05:22:57 2016 -0700 add the success&fail commit modal in orajob submit module
| * a32825c2c71fc3322c783ac4dc40b6390c2e0484 cccccc Wed Dec 28 05:14:53 2016 -0700 add the success modal in orajob submit module
* |   2c58406370930ec939a9426acfd46e8510158d04 Fan Zhihui Wed Dec 28 19:59:19 2016 +0800 Merge branch 'master' into dbaas   *** I merge my branch dbaas with master
|\ \
| |/
| * f2e94c08a830c1ae47c368120833188ad7f13494 liutttt Wed Dec 28 03:08:55 2016 -0700 tao
| *   2158e27d5da3508c9b2437d74f7cc64ed0ad39b6 Oracle Workgroup Server User Tue Dec 27 19:16:25 2016 -0700 Merge branch 'master' of github.corp.xxxxx.com:orgi/repo
| |\
| | * 730a7a49f14494b78a75f9d62412c6f415c0a0af yyyyyyyy Wed Dec 28 09:57:56 2016 +0800 add display_name to orajob_metajob
| | * 7ab725921926327a4b89ffb56b8f562dd740947e Oracle Workgroup Server User Tue Dec 27 17:52:22 2016 -0700 xxxxxx commit
| * | 89c126cd65b5fbd562bd4600ae21a7806a6c3ebc Oracle Workgroup Server User Tue Dec 27 19:16:05 2016 -0700 xxxxxx change mysqlmodul
| * | ca26c64a4d59043ddc3b1cd44d50ea4517058827 Oracle Workgroup Server User Tue Dec 27 18:46:20 2016 -0700 xxxxxx add install mysql for pw
| |/
| * 192fccdd202d0172c13d07609a4df2f0bd21dd4e cccccc Tue Dec 27 08:51:29 2016 -0700 change the arr beacause of status and result was added
| * de558d51ec33fb994dbd77bd114cb51381316467 yyyyyyyy Tue Dec 27 16:12:40 2016 +0800 enhance get_job_history api
| * 86ff5629be0d18e5604eb0bb8e93f724d902bcd8 yyyyyyyy Tue Dec 27 15:13:51 2016 +0800 restful api
| * 64519faca4dc560526120ca65c0cfeceeac69fe5 yyyyyyyy Tue Dec 27 11:16:18 2016 +0800 fix typo
| * 9350d8012aebf3b41dd1964a8d77076c7673f89c yyyyyyyy Tue Dec 27 11:09:53 2016 +0800 enhance query_db_as_dict api
| * 43150f44397c2c7e1ecfdb35bb3f869fd42fb242 yyyyyyyy Mon Dec 26 15:30:45 2016 +0800 add timeout_notified to orajob_steplog to support email out when timeout
| *   5f35a036ee99c92fcb31f2b002a722c275c46b59 Oracle Workgroup Server User Fri Dec 23 16:03:42 2016 -0700 Merge branch 'master' of github.corp.xxxxx.com:orgi/repo
| |\
| | * 8ca9ef36bdd6560a270e7a4d99879218d9f24493 Oracle Workgroup Server User Fri Dec 23 16:02:17 2016 -0700 xxxxxx add dbaas
| | * ea8bc58fbd8cc9a9303cb3aaf2f1dd9d3fd50267 Oracle Workgroup Server User Fri Dec 23 11:14:05 2016 -0700 xxxxxx skip xdcr lag during rebalance is running
| | *   caf7cd95b3594c3f853b501a45ce6ea0592d22e8 Oracle Workgroup Server User Fri Dec 23 10:48:46 2016 -0700 Merge branch 'master' of github.corp.xxxxx.com:orgi/repo
| | |\
| | * | d6518df938744380a695a4e1375523929e8fd01b Oracle Workgroup Server User Fri Dec 23 10:48:36 2016 -0700 xxxxxx
| * | | 680865252297cddb61db223eae4c36c0bdd7cbea Oracle Workgroup Server User Fri Dec 23 16:03:33 2016 -0700 xxxxxx change msyqlmodule
| | |/
| |/|
| * | 1d5d0619ad3ca92be9d8ddbaefd7d3508adbdd4a yyyyyyyy Fri Dec 23 09:48:31 2016 +0800 fix oncall email notification
| |/
| *   99c673a74edcc8cc13d2e5d507ebe088ca8ac884 Oracle Workgroup Server User Thu Dec 22 10:02:53 2016 -0700 Merge branch 'master' of github.corp.xxxxx.com:orgi/repo
| |\
| | * ad61e1817cda3d4a1cb9f681c8439f78bc488b1b Oracle Workgroup Server User Thu Dec 22 10:01:54 2016 -0700 xxxxxx add mysql fix host_down
| | * 81e8c7a1c4e5c8b3827e94af2b56072fbecb24bd liutttt Thu Dec 22 13:47:34 2016 -0700 tao
| | *   80838825dc986d092e8c62998099dfbd57a3412e liutttt Thu Dec 22 13:41:55 2016 -0700 Merge branch 'master' of github.corp.xxxxx.com:orgi/repo
| | |\
| | | * 464fcaa87d7d922b224400ae7f044baf2e34d462 cccccc Thu Dec 22 09:56:44 2016 -0700 change the orajob page to a sample demo style , you can see many charts and bars in the new orajob.html
| | | * 0231620c54c70a8a2905203282cf2c48e02d22f3 yyyyyyyy Thu Dec 22 17:26:37 2016 +0800 format code
| | | * 305cae6bc2721b623f53f157b6aa79413b96b5b2 yyyyyyyy Thu Dec 22 17:22:15 2016 +0800 refactor out common api of query_db_as_dict(db,sql)
| | | * 483f4c5ff6d8f36c1008a596c8e61fd1a3ecfc1b Zhou Yixun Thu Dec 22 16:24:24 2016 +0800 Install filebeat from action.
| | | * d05915b10528a9df3f38e2ccd4f31718603432a4 yyyyyyyy Thu Dec 22 14:58:30 2016 +0800 fix save_new_job if step/job name has space
| | | * 399a98606524e73888e70c751fce56978d4859d2 yyyyyyyy Thu Dec 22 14:48:57 2016 +0800 enhance save_new_job api
| | * | 5645ff4414bc94ada3f3a73b8625dcc63947dfd5 liutttt Thu Dec 22 13:41:42 2016 -0700 tao
| | |/
| | * 5627ddb90e7b0ec91cdd457c25a57dec0ebc0e11 liutttt Thu Dec 22 05:54:45 2016 -0700 tao
| | * 9ce971a75ed1c0a0013a236d35fe8b6ce24fb928 liutttt Thu Dec 22 05:51:34 2016 -0700 tao
| | *   22415a98503d50094c1e117ac4a9003a92f997a2 liutttt Thu Dec 22 05:34:21 2016 -0700 Merge branch 'master' of github.corp.xxxxx.com:orgi/repo
| | |\
| | | * a63c4dd60d833c3b3df489f9d15b05dcf3ebb7df Zhou Yixun Thu Dec 22 13:31:01 2016 +0800 Fix error in filebeat config, and url.
| | * | 851241e0df53021527a4d55892f2d35e80669b14 liutttt Thu Dec 22 05:33:48 2016 -0700 tao
| | |/
| | * 668d6a756ceddb07d72d211d09137332c8d94a30 liutttt Thu Dec 22 05:11:01 2016 -0700 tao
| | *   f4c44e014dde113b67076e20998c01e86720f016 liutttt Thu Dec 22 04:53:01 2016 -0700 Merge branch 'master' of github.corp.xxxxx.com:orgi/repo
| | |\
| | | * d54f3852423593a54964a11860c89c8671616afe Zhou Yixun Tue Dec 20 11:30:22 2016 +0800 filebeat support.
| | * | 76a04de8bd1f6152ab0e096c1ebb7f6de7cffdc6 liutttt Thu Dec 22 04:52:48 2016 -0700 tao
| | * | d833092c72db41ee5e25c9be3b2b10552f9f8fe3 liutttt Thu Dec 22 04:52:39 2016 -0700 tao
| | * | ba7b56ca12fd9bf328730a4b3b5e98a5a4ef8625 liutttt Thu Dec 22 04:52:31 2016 -0700 tao
| | * | 30c22bac0dd41c10bfefea320fc0bfc66b797bba liutttt Thu Dec 22 04:52:22 2016 -0700 tao
| | * | 6b850d29939a267100e4ca5c4e00e0e763f7c7c4 liutttt Thu Dec 22 04:52:12 2016 -0700 tao
| * | | d5839ac20b1dd38dfea75d56b7800e1fbf871599 Oracle Workgroup Server User Thu Dec 22 10:02:40 2016 -0700 xxxxxx host_down for mysql
| | |/
| |/|
| * | 745eac8c5bd2a428ea03fc20ef73a4497d6add70 yyyyyyyy Wed Dec 21 16:05:18 2016 +0800 add email, log, last_updated_time to get job history api
| * | 634b3c7c46fd5bc9efe701d416a8dd700ee1c8c0 sdu Tue Dec 20 21:24:02 2016 -0700 xxxxxx add couchbase metadata into database
| * | 8a4de001cf96545912c06dbfe278f11bdea93813 Oracle Workgroup Server User Tue Dec 20 10:42:27 2016 -0700 xxxxxx change get dc from fqdn
| * | f98342598769cb75bf233515af69e87203564b53 yyyyyyyy Tue Dec 20 17:23:20 2016 +0800 fix date format in get ora job history api
| * | 7e2422800767be3a7e6946ef482c2b2aa021fd79 Zhou Yixun Tue Dec 20 09:06:20 2016 -0700 Bug fix: method conflict in view.
| * | c9fae9bc9b0ed86d8bbbbebf62735c3c7e9ba8e7 Zhou Yixun Tue Dec 13 10:50:27 2016 +0800 Prepare the api and web page for add_node_page.
| * | 35f91f6584fed5e63593cb2e3ed2f5416d0dc4b0 yyyyyyyy Tue Dec 20 14:25:31 2016 +0800 fix high connection alert
| * | 23ebb2ab352e89721c8e48fbd018414c3af4d7e6 yyyyyyyy Tue Dec 20 11:20:52 2016 +0800 add time out to orajob_metastep
* | | 9412d216f082db48aeef5061e4a532be2e87149a Fan Zhihui Wed Dec 28 19:47:53 2016 +0800 make the naming standard
* | | 2db9adcc8d649d775f0c9708d3cd86c2c9c7a305 Fanhuirong Wed Dec 28 10:23:11 2016 -0700 add autocomplete , clusterlist   ****  Commit 1
* | | e9310b542addd325d092beea09ab72cd2766c9b8 Fanhuirong Wed Dec 28 08:46:16 2016 -0700 add component submit-button
* | | 5a25b62a4762d4fb2526f77219a112fda8ac54b9 Fan Zhihui Wed Dec 28 13:59:57 2016 +0800 build new js
* | | 9c797bf882c60cd4875ba1ee8aeba4a37474de3c Fan Zhihui Wed Dec 28 13:21:17 2016 +0800 added the missed repo
* | |   18afc7718de66f851e0f5a7417ffffb84babd1ab Fanhuirong Tue Dec 27 09:58:42 2016 -0700 Merge branch 'dbaas' of github.corp.xxxxx.com:orgi/repo into dbaas
|\ \ \
| * \ \   79c9dcc7ed460d048aff983ddbea18e381c965e6 Fan Zhihui Tue Dec 27 17:47:05 2016 +0800 Merge branch 'dbaas' of github.corp.xxxxx.com:orgi/repo into dbaas
```

Comment: Try running `git log --oneline --graph` in your repo and post the result here. Also, in your screenshot, please make it clear which is commit 1 and which is commit 2.

Comment: hi @MatthieuMoy,  thanks for your input. I have update my content.  btw, If I don't reply you with this comment, will you be informed by stackoverflow?

Comment: No, I don't get notified for edits so the comment is welcome. Sorry, but the question is still not exploitable. You've obfuscated your GitHub screenshot and you did not include commit ids in the screenshot, so there's no way to match your explanations to the output of `git log --graph`. You have little hope of getting an answer if you don't make more efforts to ask a clear question.

Comment: hi @MatthieuMoy,  you are absolutely right about the 'little hope'.  as for now,  my code works well with 'git merge',  so I didn't want to spend too much time on this.    If I can reproduce the issue very easily and clearly,  I will open another issue for this.  Thanks for your time and sorry for this unclear description.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like the asker no longer needs this question answered. For anyone else seeing this question and wondering why GitHub shows commits ordered incorrectly, it can be due to using interactive rebase and force pushing the branch, see https://help.github.com/articles/why-are-my-commits-in-the-wrong-order/. A couple of workarounds involve getting updated commit hashes on the branch, such as:

1. Use cherry-pick range to re-pick all your branch's commits:

   1. Note the first and last commits in the branch
   2. `git reset --hard master` (or whatever your base branch is, if not master)
   3. `git cherry-pick FirstCommit^..LastCommit`
   4. `git push origin HEAD -f`
2. Use interactive rebase to rename all commits in your branch:

   1. `git rebase -i <hash>` where hash is the commit preceding your first commit
   2. When the rebase options appear in the editor, change all of the `pick`s to `reword`s and save
   3. For each reword opportunity, tell your editor to do nothing (in vi/m, just `:q`)
   4. `git push origin HEAD -f`

I seem to have better results using option #2.

Comment: There is another SO convo about changing git timestamps. This answer describes a way to fix github misordering: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31540373/40422