# Change GIT_AUTHOR_DATE/GIT_COMMITTER_DATE date of a specific previous commit on git

Tags: git

As per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454734/how-can-one-change-the-timestamp-of-an-old-commit-in-git), it is recommended to do:

```
git filter-branch --env-filter \
    'if [ $GIT_COMMIT = <commit hash here> ]
     then
         export GIT_AUTHOR_DATE="Fri Jan 2 21:38:53 2009 -0800"
         export GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="Sat May 19 01:01:01 2007 -0700"
     fi'
```

to change the `GIT_AUTHOR_DATE` and `GIT_COMMITTER_DATE` of a previous commit.

Is there a way to do this targeting the exact branch/commit, so I don't have to filter through all my branches? This takes a while on one of my projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That filter *does* target the exact commit (and runs only on the current branch).  You can restrict it to stop copying at other (earlier) points; and if the commit is close to the branch tip, that will help speed a lot.  Remember, the current branch contains every commit that is *reachable from* its tip, even if those commits are on other branches.  For instance:

```
...--o--o--*--o--o--o   <-- master
            \
             o--o   <-- develop (HEAD)
```

There are two commits that are *only* on `develop` here, three commits that are *only* on `master`, and many (at least three, plus whatever `...` represents) that are on *both* branches, with the most recent of those being commit `*`.

If you know the hash ID of commit `*` you can write:

```
git filter-branch --env-filter \
    [snip actual filter] \
    HEAD ^<hash>
```

to tell Git to stop traversing backwards upon reaching commit `*`; or you can use the simpler:

```
git filter-branch --env-filter \
    [snip actual filter] \
    HEAD ^master
```

This excludes all three `master`-only commits from the filtering, *as well as* commit `*` and earlier.  That's quite safe since they're already not part of the action anyway: we merely use the name `master` as a short-cut to identify *all commits reachable from `master`* (so that we retain only commits reachable from `develop` and not those reachable from both names).

(Remember, Git "reaches" commits by starting at the given name(s)—in this case `develop` and `master`—and working backwards.  A prefix hat/caret `^` character means "exclude these", and `git filter-branch` only updates what it calls *positive references*, i.e., names that mean "include" rather than names that mean "exclude".  So after filter-branch has copied every commit it's going to copy, it replaces the name `develop`, which is a positive reference, but not the name `master`, which—because of the `^` prefix—is a negative reference.)