# Git: pull doesn't get up-to-date squashed commit

Tags: git, pull, squash

I have to checkout a remote Git branch: foo/bar. This branch had a single commit (made at datetime A) which has been squashed (at datetime B).
Problem: once checked-out, I see the old commit (with datetime A), not the new one.
git pull --force doesn't help me. I also tried to delete my local branche, fetch, check-out, pull.

Comment: what do you mean "`git pull --force` doesn't help me" ? Do you have an error message ? how do you know there is a squashed commit B instead of the A commit ? Someone told you, or did you see the discrepancy by looking at your local "origin/foobar" branch ?

Comment: Is it just the datetime that is wrong? i.e. are the contents of the commit correct? I haven't looked closely at git squash, but I know that if you `git --amend` then it leaves the timestamp and author untouched

Comment: no error: it simply doesn't change anything. And yes, the author told me he squashed his commit.

Comment: Ok, I'll check files to see if it's up to date. Thx.

Comment: You are right, content is actually up to date. Also, I used SmartGit to show git log: it indicates something like "commit at datetime A (changed at datetime B)". So, it seems ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation on rewriting history](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History):

> s, squash = use commit, but meld into previous commit

By default, during an interactive rebase, if you meld the commit messages together during a squash the commit timestamp and author on the original commit (the one you're melding into) are left unchanged. If you want to update these, then select `edit` instead of `pick` for the base commit.
This will then stop the rebase on that commit, giving you the chance to `git commit --amend` and update meta information about the commit.

[Here's a related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5017265/5074609) dealing with modifying the dates of previous commits if you want that information to be updated.