# How to change a commit time stamp on github after pushing?

Tags: github, github-api

I had to deliver a school task a day ago on github, but there were some problems with me yesterday and i pushed the last version today and i need to change their dates on github. Is it possible to make the last commit data on github yesterday?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can one change the timestamp of an old commit in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454734/how-can-one-change-the-timestamp-of-an-old-commit-in-git). Hmm, but it looks like that post might not be relevant if you already pushed -- I think there might not be anything you can do if you've already pushed.

Comment: @HaydenSchiff so there is no way to change a github commit timestamp after pushing, right?

Comment: @HaydenSchiff so neglicting the fact that i already pushed. if i changed a commit timestamp on my computer to make it yesterday and push it to git now. what will be the commit timestamp on github?