# How to delete a commit that "hasn't happened yet"?

Tags: git, github

I pushed a commit with date in the future:

[image]

I want to delete it but:

- I only found ways to do it with my local repo
- I made that commit in a machine that is currently unavailable
- That commit doesn't appear in my current machine even if I pull

Is there a way to delete it using github's web interface?

Is there a way to "force pull" that commit to delete it locally and then push the deletion?

---

**Update**

I found the commit but it had a different time than the one shown in github
[image]

I tried modifying the commit using `git rebase <id> -i` but the commit doesn't appear in the rebase

[image]

The commit that I'm trying to change is the one that starts with 03.

Comment: You don't need to get it locally to delete it. Just make sure your local branch's latest commit is the one from Nov. 8, and force push your local branch.

Comment: Very nice, how did you commit on Dec 2201?

Comment: I guess setting the time of the computer to be in the future is a way. And I think there are environment variables to set whatever values we want for author and committer dates.

Comment: @JBNizet, I found the commit but I can't modify it. I updated the question. Karol Dowbecki, eftshift0, I have no idea why it happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding a rebase, make sure to start it with the commit *before* the one you want to change, or it won't be part of your rebase task list.

But I would use a [`git filter-branch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch) [as this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/454750/6309), in order to hcange the author date of a commit.

```
git filter-branch --env-filter \
    'if [ $GIT_COMMIT = 03...]
     then
         export GIT_AUTHOR_DATE="Fri Jan 2 21:38:53 2009 -0800"
         export GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="Sat May 19 01:01:01 2007 -0700"
     fi' SHA1..HEAD
```

Again: make sure SHA1 is the one *before* the 03... you want to change.