# How to get the last change date of a git commit?

Tags: git

git log will show the original commit date even if the commit gets amended or rebased. Is it possible to show the time of last such operation?

Comment: Amending *does* change the commit date, if you also want to change the author date see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/454734/3001761

Comment: Thanks for the link and the helpful "author date" suggestion, I can answer myself now!

Answer (score 1):

git stores two dates on a commit: author date and commit date. By default, the author date is shown. `git log --format=fuller` shows both. Also, `git log --format=format:%ad%cd` will show the author date and the commit date respectively, there are many options for both, see `man git log` for more.