# How Can I change the date of a git commit

Tags: git, github

I need to push some code upstream into my repo. However I would like to see if It is possible to set the date of the commit/push to be something other than the current the date.This would mean if someone visited my github page and my desired date for the push was 00/00/00 it would show as 00/00/00 and NOT the current date.Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: Don't think it is possible. Look at https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/commits.html . The `committed_date` is probably to be set  by github only.

Comment: Technically, you cannot change *anything* about any *existing* commit. What you can do is make a new (different) commit that's almost exactly the same as the existing commit, but has whatever it is that you want to be different, different. That's what `git commit --amend` does, but note that `00/00/0000` isn't possible as it's not  a valid date. `2000-01-01` (note the `01`s) is a valid date.

Comment: Once you've made a new commit, you'll have to convince that other Git on GitHub to stop using the old commit and start using the new one. That generally requires `git push --force` or `git push --force-with-lease`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can one change the timestamp of an old commit in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454734/how-can-one-change-the-timestamp-of-an-old-commit-in-git)

Answer (score 38):

You can change the date of last commit:

```
git commit --amend --no-edit --date=now
```

or input date:

```
git commit --amend --no-edit --date="2020.11.02 12:00"
```

Comment: Thanks .This does not change the date in my github repo profile.It does change the date of the commit in my local repo.I am looking for a way to have the change show up once I push the code upstream.

Comment: This does *not* change the date of the last commit.  It creates a new commit that has the same underlying tree.

Comment: Yes, do you have some alternatives?

Answer (score 11):

You can use the environment variable `GIT_COMMITTER_DATE` to update commit date as well.

```
export GIT_COMMITTER_DATE='Wed Dec 21 11:51:39 IST 2022'
git commit --amend --no-edit --date='Wed Dec 21 11:51:39 IST 2022'
unset GIT_COMMITTER_DATE
```

To see if your change has taken effect,

```
git log --pretty=fuller
```

(of course, you will need to do a force-push, if you have already pushed the commit to upstream)