# What is this editor opened by "git commit --amend" in Windows 10 cmd and how do I use it?

Tags: windows, git, vim, cmd, text-editor

[image: Editor opened by default when using "git commit --amend" in Windows 10 cmd.]

Windows 10 cmd opens up this editor by default when I try to edit a GIT commit message. Can you please tell me what that is and how I can use it? Thanks.

Comment: It should also be possible to configure Git to use a different editor.

Comment: I think git is a very powerful scm. so I guess the default editor taken by Git should be very powerful as well.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It is [Vim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_(text_editor)), the default editor in Git installation. It is rather hard to use if you don't know how to use it! It is not trivial as other editors like Notepad++, Emacs or Sublime Text, though it is very powerful, and when you mastered it (it takes a few month of hard work! :) ), you'l become highly productive.

However you can easily configure git to use another editor. Fire up a command line and enter:

```
git config --global core.editor notepad
```

Now Windows Notepad is your default editor in git. You can easily change it to any editor of your choice. See [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-First-Time-Git-Setup) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10564/how-can-i-set-up-an-editor-to-work-with-git-on-windows) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22631863/setting-up-sublimetext-3-as-git-commit-text-editor).

By the way, I recommend you to [put the time and learn Vim! You'll not regret it :)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597077/what-are-the-benefits-of-learning-vim)

Comment: As someone who just doesn't like Vim but wants to Keep that light-weight console workflow: ```git config --global core.editor nano```. Way easier to learn, works on all Unix systems (including macOS) and I just tested it on Windows with git. Works like a charm!

Comment: From version 2.15.1, Git for Windows comes with "nano", and can be configured to use nano or Notepad++ straight from the installer.

Answer (score 15):

It Vi and you have to write your message.
If you are unfamiliar with VI i recommend to go over [this interactive tutorial](http://www.openvim.com/tutorial.html)

[image]

#### To edit the file and to write your commit message (insert mode)

<kbd>i</kbd>

#### To save your data:

Write  + quit: <kbd>ESC</kbd> + <kbd>:</kbd> + <kbd>w</kbd> + <kbd>q</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>

#### To save your without saving data:

Write  + quit: <kbd>ESC</kbd> + <kbd>:</kbd> + <kbd>q</kbd> + <kbd>!</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: `ESC`+`w`+`q` does not work for me. But `ESC` + `:` + `w` + `q` + `ENTER` works. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Ves You aren't doing anything wrong, the answer just didn't mention those keys; I've added them.

Answer (score 0):

try git config --global core.editor (any editor of your choice or if you have any of the following: Atom / Sublimetext/ notepad++/ notepad / etc)

in either Visual studio terminal while coding for git or in any command line.

example:-
git config --global core.editor Atom