# How to delete a gist on GitHub?

Tags: github, gist

Is there a way I can remove a gist on GitHub? Created a gist earlier, but don't really want it there anymore.

Comment: Why is this post downvoted and closed as off topic, while http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5912274/how-to-delete-a-specific-revision-of-a-github-gist is not?

Comment: I vote for reopen. On-topic, as per the FAQ: 'software tools commonly used by programmers'. Just sayin' :)

Comment: This post is the #1 hit if you google "github delete gist"

Comment: The delete button is not that easy to find, it doesn't appear on all display styles of the gist, that's why this is a top google hit and has 27 upvotes despite some downvotes!

Comment: Delete ALL gists here: https://github.com/lateplate/gist-cleaner/blob/master/gist_cleaner.rb

Answer (score 82, accepted):

#### Currently:

There's a "delete" button at the top of each gist now:

[image]

#### Previously...

Previously there was "delete this gist" link at the bottom of the gist's page, as below - thanks to [Daniel Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/822005/daniel-smith) for pointing out in the comments below that this has been changed.

[image]

Comment: Yup, just found it and posted an answer about my dumbness, haha. But you have a screenshot, so will accept this one!

Comment: At least now there is an answer on SO which hopefully shows up on Google if someone else manages to overlook that red link... :P

Comment: That's the most difficult topic I've seen answered so far! thank God I google it first, I was about to ask on IRC (and get probably trashed) hehe, God bless stackOverflow :-P

Comment: **The delete button has now moved to the top of the gist's page**

Comment: Note: the delete functionality is *only* available when you posted it while logged in. Anonymous gists cannot be removed.

Comment: @Lekensteyn You definitely **can** delete anonymous Gists, at least as long as you don't navigate away.

Comment: This answer helped: I first swore at it, because there was no delete button. Then I wondered if I was looking in the right place, and realised that I was looking at a summary of gists, not an individual gist. One needs to enter the gist to delete it. (this may prove confusing to any MS-Windows user that has ever deleted a file)

Answer (score 3):

I created a tool which can help you delete multiple github gists both `secret` and `public` gists at once.  https://gist-cleaner.ndolestudio.com

It's open source, you can find the source code here https://github.com/NdoleStudio/gist-cleaner