# How to fill in an empty commit message?

Tags: git

Until a minute ago, I had a Git repo where the last commit had an empty commit message. I've filled it in by squashing a new commit onto it with `git rebase -i` (I was planning to amend the contents anyway) but I would still like to know if there's a proper way to fill in empty commit messages.

I tried

```
git commit --amend
```

but that didn't work, then I tried

```
git rebase -i HEAD^
```

and a `reword`. Both attempts resulted in Git saying

```
fatal: commit has empty message
```

and quitting.

**EDIT**: to clarify, what finally worked was

```
# change some stuff
git commit
git rebase -i HEAD~2
# squash the last two commits
```

but this seems like a hack.

Comment: Note: you should have `fatal: commit has empty message` anymore with git 2.0.1 (June 2014). See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24974304/6309)

Comment: Note that you now (Q1 2018, Git 2.17) rebase with allowing empty commit messages. See "[Rebasing a git history with empty commit messages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48977896/6309)"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This seems to be a [bug](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/PATCH-commit-allow-amend-c-foo-when-HEAD-foo-has-empty-message-td7324888.html) which hasn't been fixed yet (although there are proposed patches for it). As a workaround, you can provide the message on the command line:

```
git commit --amend -m "foo"
```

Answer (score 3):

If you need to edit your last commit (HEAD) message use `git commit --amend -m 'new message'`

```
$ git commit --allow-empty --allow-empty-message -m ''
[master 5db8236] 

$ git commit --amend
fatal: commit has empty message

$ git commit --allow-empty --amend -m 'new message'
[master d383d5c] new message
```

Keep in mind i'm using `--allow-empty` just to force `git commit` create an empty commit and `--allow-empty-message` to force `git commit` to create a commit with an empty message.

Comment: If you are trying to edit the first commit, it's way more complicated.

Comment: The commit with empty message was the `HEAD` when I tried to `commit --amend` it. Clarified the question, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @larsmans Ok, actually i didn't try with an empty message last time, it seems it generates more warnings and errors than i expected. Try my new approach, it seems to do what you want.

Answer (score 3):

Starting git 2.0.1 (June 25, 2014), git won't complain anymore of an empty commit message when you rebase and attempt to put one.

See [commit 076cbd6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/076cbd6341182d296671cb101c75145eb3bfda0a) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff)

#### `commit`: do not complain of empty messages from `-C`

> When we pick another commit's message, we `die()` immediately if we find that it's empty and we are not going to run an editor (i.e., when running "`-C`" instead of "`-c`").
>   However, this check is redundant and harmful.
>
> It's redundant because we will already notice the empty message later, after we would have run the editor, and die there (just as we would for a regular, not "`-C`" case, where
>   the user provided an empty message in the editor).
>
> It's harmful for a few reasons:
>
> 1. It does not respect `--allow-empty-message`. **As a result, a "`git rebase -i`" cannot "pick" such a commit**.
>      So you cannot even go back in time to fix it with a "`reword`" or "`edit`" instruction.
> 2. It does not take into account other ways besides the editor to modify the message.
>      For example, "`git commit -C empty-commit -m foo`" could take the author information from empty-commit, but add a message to it.
>      There's more to do to make that work correctly (and right now we explicitly forbid "`-C` with `-m`"), but this removes one roadblock.
> 3. The existing check is not enough to prevent segfaults.
>      We try to find the "`\n\n`" header/body boundary in the commit. If it is at the end of the string (i.e., no body), *or* if we cannot find it at all (i.e., a truncated commit object), we consider the message empty.
>      With "`-C`", that's OK; we `die` in either case. But with "`-c`", we continue on, and in the case of a truncated commit may end up dereferencing `NULL+2`.

---

Note: with Git 2.19, `git rebase` will use `--allow-empty-message` by default.
See "[Rebasing a git history with empty commit messages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48977896/6309)".

---

Make sure to use Git 2.25 (Q1 2020) though: The sequencer machinery compared the HEAD and the state it is attempting to commit to decide if the result would be a no-op commit, even when amending a commit, which was incorrect, and has been corrected.

See [commit 2d05ef2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2d05ef2778b99e05e6a8a40c5b8d59a3c4ab1274) (22 Nov 2019) by [Phillip Wood (`phillipwood`)](https://github.com/phillipwood).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit c920859](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c9208597a986509e6ce9b3c7936fd7a2b3bb3e43), 05 Dec 2019)</sup>

> ### [`sequencer`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2d05ef2778b99e05e6a8a40c5b8d59a3c4ab1274): fix empty commit check when amending
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Phillip Wood</sup>
>
> This fixes a regression introduced in [356ee4659b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/356ee4659bb551cd9464b317d691827276752c2d) ("`sequencer`: try to commit without forking 'git commit'", 2017-11-24, Git v2.17.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1772ad1125a6f8a5473d73bbd17162bb20ebd825) listed in [batch #2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b2e45c695d09f6a31ce09347ae0a5d2cdfe9dd4e)).
>   When amending a commit `try_to_commit()` was using the wrong parent when checking if the commit would be empty. When amending we need to check against `HEAD^` not `HEAD`.
>
> That series will mutate these tests to check that the advice includes suggesting `rebase --skip` to skip the fixup that would empty the commit.