# git: how to rebase several commits into one

Tags: git, rebase

Here's my current log, from most recent commit to least recent:

```
E   I want this message
D   I don't want this message
C   Don't want this message
B   Don't want this message
A   Want this commit separately
```

I want to squash commits B-E into a single commit, and keep commit A separate, so that it looks like this:

```
F   I want this message
A   Want this commit separately
```

Where `F` contains all changes from `B` through `E`.  I've tried this:

`git rebase -i A`

```
pick A Want this commit separately
reword B I want this message
fixup C
fixup D
fixup E
```

It prompts me for a commit message, auto-populating the existing message from commit `B`, then it fails, saying `You asked to amend the most recent commit, but doing so would make it empty.`

How can I get the history I want?

Comment: that seems to have done it. thanks. want to post an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37599665/3282436):

You may be able to:

```
git commit --allow-empty
git rebase --continue
git rebase -i HEAD~~
# fixup or remove second (empty) commit
```